# How to query MongoDB with "like"

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query, sql-like

I want to query something with SQL's `like` query:

```
SELECT * FROM users  WHERE name LIKE '%m%'
```

How can I achieve the same in MongoDB? I can't find an operator for `like` in [the documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries).

Comment: see mongodb's docs: Advanced Queries -- Regular expressions
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions

Comment: I seriously suggest taking a look at MongoDB Atlas Search, as it is much more resource efficient and feature rich for "like"-like queries that `$text` or `$regex`

Comment: MongoDB Compass: `{"field_name": { "$regex": "textOrRegex"}}` (is roughly equivalent of `LIKE '%text%'`; `LIKE 'text%'`=> `'^text'`; `LIKE '%text` => `'text$'`) note that it's case SENSITIVE by default => `'$options': 'i'` will make it insensitive.

Answer (score 2530, accepted):

That would have to be:

```
db.users.find({"name": /.*m.*/})
```

Or, similar:

```
db.users.find({"name": /m/})
```

You're looking for something that contains "m" somewhere (SQL's '`%`' operator is equivalent to regular expressions' '`.*`'), not something that has "m" anchored to the beginning of the string.

**Note:** MongoDB uses regular expressions [(see docs)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/reference/operator/query/regex/#syntax) which are more powerful than "LIKE" in SQL. With regular expressions you can create any pattern that you imagine.

For more information on regular expressions, refer to *[Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)* (MDN).

Comment: is searching by regex expensive?

Comment: Actually, it depends. If the query doesn't use an index, and must do a table scan, then it can certainly be expensive. If you're doing a 'starts with' regex query, then that can use an index. Best to run an explain() to see what's happening.

Comment: When not anchored to the beginning of the string, it is somewhat expensive. But then again, so is a `LIKE` query in SQL.

Comment: I would add regex i
```javascript

db.users.find({ "name": { $regex: /m/i } })


```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that if you want to use it from Node app and you want a dynamic search, you can use: 

`users.find({"name": new RegExp('.*' + searchVariable + '.*')})`

So, this way you can use it with other operators like $in, $nin, etc.

Comment: @Ivan Cabrera, yes it is worth noting, as is putting '.*' anywhere there is whitespace. Othrer DBMS's allow perppered %.

Comment: Why ".*" at the beginning and end of the regex seems "optional" in you example? Does Mongo treat the regex /somePattern/ automatically as "contains somePattern"?

Comment: showing syntax error for /m/ while using pymongo. what is correct syntax in python?

Comment: Just make sure that you escape the values that you place in this regex correctly especially if this is something that a user can input values into. You can cause Mongo to throw exceptions if its not properly escaped.

Comment: Please not that these is no quotations in /m/

Answer (score 647):

```
db.users.insert({name: 'patrick'})
db.users.insert({name: 'petra'})
db.users.insert({name: 'pedro'})
```

Therefore:

For:

```
db.users.find({name: /a/})  // Like '%a%'
```

Output: *patrick, petra*

For:

```
db.users.find({name: /^pa/}) // Like 'pa%'
```

Output: *patrick*

For:

```
db.users.find({name: /ro$/}) // Like '%ro'
```

Output: *pedro*

Comment: You know why you have so many upvotes? Because the docs deserve equal many downvotes! Thank you

Comment: To search for strings with forward slashes in them, just escape it like so: `db.users.find({name: /^path\/to\/something/}) // Like 'path/to/something%'`

Comment: Performance wise, $regex is not the best approach...

Comment: Regex is the only way to answer the OPs question in MongoDB. Therefore there is no other approach @Danielle

Answer (score 389):

In

- **PyMongo** using **Python**
- **Mongoose** using **Node.js**
- **Jongo**, using **Java**
- **mgo**, using **Go**

you can do:

```
db.users.find({'name': {'$regex': 'sometext'}})
```

Comment: @TahirYasin if you're still wondering, case-insensitive search would be done like this: `db.users.find({'name': {'$regex': 'sometext', '$options': 'i'}})`

Comment: this applies to the whole word, not to a part of the word.

Answer (score 108):

In PHP, you could use the following code:

```
$collection->find(array('name'=> array('$regex' => 'm'));
```

Comment: You can also specify the flags in the second item of the $regex array, like so: `$collection->find(array('name'=> array('$regex' => 'm', '$options => 'i'));`

Answer (score 108):

Here are different types of requirements and solutions for string search with regular expressions.

You can do with a regular expression which contains a word, i.e., *like*. Also you can use `$options => i` for a case insensitive search.

#### Contains `string`

```
db.collection.find({name:{'$regex' : 'string', '$options' : 'i'}})
```

#### Doesn't contain `string`, only with a regular expression

```
db.collection.find({name:{'$regex' : '^((?!string).)*$', '$options' : 'i'}})
```

#### Exact case insensitive `string`

```
db.collection.find({name:{'$regex' : '^string$', '$options' : 'i'}})
```

#### Start with `string`

```
db.collection.find({name:{'$regex' : '^string', '$options' : 'i'}})
```

#### End with `string`

```
db.collection.find({name:{'$regex' : 'string$', '$options' : 'i'}})
```

Keep *[Regular Expressions Cheat Sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)* as a bookmark, and a reference for any other alterations you may need.

Comment: this is a later comment but, how can I use a variable in above example? like let name = 'john doe' . how can I implement name variable in regex? thanks

Answer (score 74):

You would use a regular expression for that in MongoDB.

For example,

```
db.users.find({"name": /^m/})
```

Comment: I think this only shows documents with a name value that starts with "m"

Comment: Important to remove quotes when you use regex, i.e. don't do "/^m/", just do /^m/

Answer (score 58):

You have two choices:

```
db.users.find({"name": /string/})
```

or

```
db.users.find({"name": {"$regex": "string", "$options": "i"}})
```

For the second one, you have more options, like "i" in options to find using case insensitive.

And about the "string", you can use like ".*string.*" (%string%), or "string.*" (string%) and ".*string) (%string) for example. You can use a regular expression as you want.

Answer (score 47):

If using **Node.js**, [it says](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) that you can write this:

```
db.collection.find( { field: /acme.*corp/i } );

// Or
db.collection.find( { field: { $regex: 'acme.*corp', $options: 'i' } } );
```

[Also](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), you can write this:

```
db.collection.find( { field: new RegExp('acme.*corp', 'i') } );
```

Comment: Thanks @Eddy. Providing '$options: 'i'' with regex made refactoring process to easy for me.

Answer (score 32):

Already you got the answers, but to match with a regular expression with case insensitivity, you could use the following query:

```
db.users.find ({ "name" : /m/i } ).pretty()
```

The `i` in the `/m/i` indicates case insensitivity and `.pretty()` provides a prettier output.

Answer (score 25):

For [Mongoose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongoose_%28web_server%29) in Node.js:

```
db.users.find({'name': {'$regex': '.*sometext.*'}})
```

Answer (score 22):

In MongoDb, can use like using [MongoDb reference operator regular expression(regex)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/).

For Same Ex.

```
MySQL - SELECT * FROM users  WHERE name LIKE '%m%'

MongoDb

    1) db.users.find({ "name": { "$regex": "m", "$options": "i" } })

    2) db.users.find({ "name": { $regex: new RegExp("m", 'i') } })

    3) db.users.find({ "name": { $regex:/m/i } })

    4) db.users.find({ "name": /mail/ })

    5) db.users.find({ "name": /.*m.*/ })

MySQL - SELECT * FROM users  WHERE name LIKE 'm%'

MongoDb Any of Above with /^String/

    6) db.users.find({ "name": /^m/ })

MySQL - SELECT * FROM users  WHERE name LIKE '%m'

MongoDb Any of Above with /String$/

    7) db.users.find({ "name": /m$/ })
```

Comment: It becomes extremely slow on large datasets just FYI. And there's no way to know what the score is.

Answer (score 19):

With MongoDB Compass, you need to use the strict mode syntax, as such:

```
{ "text": { "$regex": "^Foo.*", "$options": "i" } }
```

(In MongoDB Compass, it's important that you use `"` instead of `'`)

Comment: This nearly drove me crazy much appreciated, and why can't they give documentation or examples on doing things like this for Compass. I couldn't even find documentation on the strict mode syntax for Compass.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the new feature of MongoDB 2.6:

```
db.foo.insert({desc: "This is a string with text"});
db.foo.insert({desc:"This is a another string with Text"});
db.foo.ensureIndex({"desc":"text"});
db.foo.find({
    $text:{
        $search:"text"
    }
});
```

Comment: Note, AFAIK Mongodb's text searching works on whole words only by default, so this will match values like "This is a string with text", but not "This is a string with subtext".  So it's not quite like sql's "LIKE" operator.

Answer (score 16):

In a **Node.js** project and using [Mongoose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongoose_%28web_server%29), use a *like* query:

```
var User = mongoose.model('User');

var searchQuery = {};
searchQuery.email = req.query.email;
searchQuery.name = {$regex: req.query.name, $options: 'i'};
User.find(searchQuery, function(error, user) {
                if(error || user === null) {
                    return res.status(500).send(error);
                }
                return res.status(200).send(user);
            });
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use a *where* statement to build any JavaScript script:

```
db.myCollection.find( { $where: "this.name.toLowerCase().indexOf('m') >= 0" } );
```

Reference: *[$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where/)*

Comment: `$where` is highly inefficient. Do full collection scan :(

Answer (score 15):

String yourdb={deepakparmar, dipak, parmar}

```
db.getCollection('yourdb').find({"name":/^dee/})
```

ans **deepakparmar**

```
db.getCollection('yourdb').find({"name":/d/})
```

ans **deepakparmar, dipak**

```
db.getCollection('yourdb').find({"name":/mar$/})
```

ans **deepakparmar, parmar**

Answer (score 13):

In Go and the *mgo* driver:

```
Collection.Find(bson.M{"name": bson.RegEx{"m", ""}}).All(&result)
```

where the result is the struct instance of the sought-after type.

Comment: pls avoid unkeyed fields in literals, do `bson:RegEx{Pattern:"m", Options:"i"}` instead

Answer (score 13):

In SQL, the ‘**like**’ query looks like this:

```
select * from users where name like '%m%'
```

In the MongoDB console, it looks like this:

```
db.users.find({"name": /m/})     // Not JSON formatted

db.users.find({"name": /m/}).pretty()  // JSON formatted
```

In addition, the `pretty()` method will produce a formatted JSON structure in all the places which is more readable.

Answer (score 13):

For PHP mongo *Like*.

I had several issues with PHP mongo *like*. I found that concatenating the regular expression parameters helps in some situations - *[PHP mongo find field starts with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872398/php-mongo-find-field-starts-with)*.

For example,

```
db()->users->insert(['name' => 'john']);
db()->users->insert(['name' => 'joe']);
db()->users->insert(['name' => 'jason']);

// starts with
$like_var = 'jo';
$prefix = '/^';
$suffix = '/';
$name = $prefix . $like_var . $suffix;
db()->users->find(['name' => array('$regex'=>new MongoRegex($name))]);
output: (joe, john)

// contains
$like_var = 'j';
$prefix = '/';
$suffix = '/';
$name = $prefix . $like_var . $suffix;
db()->users->find(['name' => array('$regex'=>new MongoRegex($name))]);

output: (joe, john, jason)
```

Answer (score 11):

Using template literals with variables also works:

`` {"firstname": {$regex : `^${req.body.firstname}.*` , $options: 'si' }} ``

Comment: This doesn't work. Inputting names with special characters (for example `(`) fails.

Comment: Are those valid variable names? Or do you mean: req.body.firstname = "John(Jimmy) Doe"?

Comment: The second one yes.

Answer (score 10):

Regular expressions are expensive to process.

Another way is to create an index of text and then search it using `$search`.

Create a text *index* of fields you want to make searchable:

```
db.collection.createIndex({name: 'text', otherField: 'text'});
```

Search for a string in the text index:

```
db.collection.find({
  '$text'=>{'$search': "The string"}
})
```

Comment: This doesn't work with partials.

Answer (score 8):

Use regular expressions matching as below. The 'i' shows case insensitivity.

```
var collections = mongoDatabase.GetCollection("Abcd");

var queryA = Query.And(
         Query.Matches("strName", new BsonRegularExpression("ABCD", "i")), 
         Query.Matches("strVal", new BsonRegularExpression("4121", "i")));

var queryB = Query.Or(
       Query.Matches("strName", new BsonRegularExpression("ABCD","i")),
       Query.Matches("strVal", new BsonRegularExpression("33156", "i")));

var getA = collections.Find(queryA);
var getB = collections.Find(queryB);
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems that there are reasons for using both the JavaScript `/regex_pattern/` pattern as well as the MongoDB `{'$regex': 'regex_pattern'}` pattern. See: [MongoDB RegEx Syntax Restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#syntax-restrictions)

This is not a complete regular expression tutorial, but I was inspired to run these tests after seeing a [highly voted ambiguous post above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23761146/117471).

```
> ['abbbb','bbabb','bbbba'].forEach(function(v){db.test_collection.insert({val: v})})

> db.test_collection.find({val: /a/})
{ "val" : "abbbb" }
{ "val" : "bbabb" }
{ "val" : "bbbba" }

> db.test_collection.find({val: /.*a.*/})
{ "val" : "abbbb" }
{ "val" : "bbabb" }
{ "val" : "bbbba" }

> db.test_collection.find({val: /.+a.+/})
{ "val" : "bbabb" }

> db.test_collection.find({val: /^a/})
{ "val" : "abbbb" }

> db.test_collection.find({val: /a$/})
{ "val" : "bbbba" }

> db.test_collection.find({val: {'$regex': 'a$'}})
{ "val" : "bbbba" }
```

Answer (score 6):

A *like* query would be as shown below:

```
db.movies.find({title: /.*Twelve Monkeys.*/}).sort({regularizedCorRelation : 1}).limit(10);
```

For the Scala [ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/) API,

```
val query = BSONDocument("title" -> BSONRegex(".*" + name + ".*", "")) // like
val sortQ = BSONDocument("regularizedCorRelation" -> BSONInteger(1))
val cursor = collection.find(query).sort(sortQ).options(QueryOpts().batchSize(10)).cursor[BSONDocument]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Spring-Data MongoDB, you can do it in this way:

```
String tagName = "m";
Query query = new Query();
query.limit(10);
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("tagName").regex(tagName));
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have a string variable, you must convert it to a regex, so MongoDB will use a like statement on it.

```
const name = req.query.title; //John
db.users.find({ "name": new Regex(name) });
```

Is the same result as:

```
db.users.find({"name": /John/})
```

Answer (score 5):

One way to find the result as with equivalent to a *like* query:

```
db.collection.find({name:{'$regex' : 'string', '$options' : 'i'}})
```

*Where `i` is used for a case-insensitive fetch data.*

Another way by which we can also get the result:

```
db.collection.find({"name":/aus/})
```

The above will provide the result which has the *aus* in the name containing *aus*.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a 'like' search in MongoDB then you should go with *$regex*. By using it, the query will be:

```
db.product.find({name:{$regex:/m/i}})
```

For more, you can read the documentation as well - *[$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)*

Answer (score 4):

Use aggregation substring search (with index!!!):

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
        $project : {
            fieldExists : {
                $indexOfBytes : ['$field', 'string']
            }
        }
    }, {
        $match : {
            fieldExists : {
                $gt : -1
            }
        }
    }, {
        $limit : 5
    }
]);
```

Comment: This might still be better than all these regex suggestions - but it still does a colscan.

Answer (score 4):

You can query with a regular expression:

```js
db.users.find({"name": /m/});
```

If the string is coming from the user, maybe you want to escape the string before using it. This will prevent literal chars from the user to be interpreted as regex tokens.

For example, searching the string "A." [will also match](https://regexone.com/lesson/wildcards_dot) "AB" if not escaped.
You can use a simple `replace` to escape your string before using it. I made it a function for reusing:

```js
function textLike(str) {
  var escaped = str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, '\\$&');
  return new RegExp(escaped, 'i');
}
```

So now, the string becomes a case-insensitive pattern matching also the literal dot. Example:

```
>  textLike('A.');
<  /A\./i
```

Now we are ready to generate the regular expression on the go:

```js
db.users.find({ "name": textLike("m") });
```

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
const indexSearch = await UserModel.find(
      { $text: { $search: filter } },
    );

    if (indexSearch.length) {
      return indexSearch;
    }
    return UserModel.find(
      {
        $or: [
          { firstName: { $regex: `^${filter}`, $options: 'i' } },
          { lastName: { $regex: `^${filter}`, $options: 'i' } },
          { middleName: { $regex: `^${filter}`, $options: 'i' } },
          { email: { $regex: `^${filter}`, $options: 'i' } },
        ],
      },
    );
```

I used a combination of regex and "index".

Answer (score 3):

As the MongoDB shell supports regular expressions, that's completely possible.

```
db.users.findOne({"name" : /.*sometext.*/});
```

If we want the query to be case-insensitive, we can use the "i" option, like shown below:

```
db.users.findOne({"name" : /.*sometext.*/i});
```

Answer (score 3):

MongoRegex has been deprecated.

Use *MongoDB\BSON\Regex*:

```
$regex = new MongoDB\BSON\Regex ( '^m');
$cursor = $collection->find(array('users' => $regex));
//iterate through the cursor
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
db.customer.find({"customerid": {"$regex": "CU_00000*", "$options": "i"}}).pretty()
```

When we are searching for string patterns, it is always better to use the above pattern as when we are not sure about case.

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways to accomplish this.

The simplest one:

```
db.users.find({"name": /m/})

{ <field>: { $regex: /pattern/, $options: '<options>' } }
{ <field>: { $regex: 'pattern', $options: '<options>' } }
{ <field>: { $regex: /pattern/<options> } }

db.users.find({ "name": { $regex: "m"} })
```

More details can be found in *[$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)*.

Answer (score 3):

#### Using a JavaScript RegExp

- split the `name` string by space and make an array of words
- map to an iterate loop and convert the string to a regex of each word of the name

```js
let name = "My Name".split(" ").map(n => new RegExp(n));
console.log(name);
```

Result:

```
[/My/, /Name/]
```

There are two scenarios to match a string,

1. **`$in`:** *(it is similar to the `$or` condition)*

Try [$in Expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#in-expressions). To include a regular expression in an `$in` query expression, you can only use JavaScript regular expression objects (i.e., `/pattern/`). For example:

```
db.users.find({ name: { $in: name } }); // name = [/My/, /Name/]
```

2. **`$all`:** *(it is similar to a `$and` condition)* a document should contain all words

```
db.users.find({ name: { $all: name } }); // name = [/My/, /Name/]
```

#### Using nested `$and` and `$or` conditionals and `$regex`

There are two scenarios to match a string,

1. **`$or`:** *(it is similar to the `$in` condition)*

```
db.users.find({
  $or: [
    { name: { $regex: "My" } },
    { name: { $regex: "Name" } }
    // if you have multiple fields for search then repeat same block
  ]
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zQ9Q-c1Tkai)

2. **`$and`:** *(it is similar to the `$all` condition)* a document should contain all words

```
db.users.find({
  $and: [
    {
      $and: [
        { name: { $regex: "My" } },
        { name: { $regex: "Name" } }
      ]
    }
    // if you have multiple fields for search then repeat same block
  ]
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/csp6lh3TGVH)

Answer (score 2):

I found a free tool to translate *MySQL* queries to MongoDB: http://www.querymongo.com/

I checked with several queries. As I see it, almost all of them are correct. According to that, the answer is

```
db.users.find({
    "name": "%m%"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**For the Go driver:**

```
filter := bson.M{
    "field_name": primitive.Regex{
        Pattern: keyword,
        Options: "",
    },
}
cursor, err := GetCollection().Find(ctx, filter)
```

Use a regex in the $in query (MongoDB documentation: *[$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-with-a-regular-expression)*):

```
filter := bson.M{
    "field_name": bson.M{
        "$in": []primitive.Regex{
            {
                Pattern: keyword,
                Options: "",
            },
        }
    }
}
cursor, err := GetCollection().Find(ctx, filter)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP, you can use the [MongoDB_DataObject](https://github.com/viettranme/MongoDB_DataObject) wrapper like below:

```
$model = new MongoDB_DataObject();

$model->query("select * from users where name like '%m%'");

while($model->fetch()) {
    var_dump($model);
}
```

*Or*:

```
$model = new MongoDB_DataObject('users);

$model->whereAdd("name like '%m%'");

$model->find();

while($model->fetch()) {
    var_dump($model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**FullName like 'last' with status==’Pending’ between two dates:**

```
db.orders.find({
      createdAt:{$gt:ISODate("2017-04-25T10:08:16.111Z"),
      $lt:ISODate("2017-05-05T10:08:16.111Z")},
      status:"Pending",
      fullName:/last/}).pretty();
```

**status== 'Pending' and orderId LIKE ‘PHA876174’:**

```
db.orders.find({
     status:"Pending",
     orderId:/PHA876174/
     }).pretty();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>> db.car.distinct('name')
[ "honda", "tat", "tata", "tata3" ]

>> db.car.find({"name":/. *ta.* /})
```

Comment: Wow, this is probably an amazing answer. Care to elaborate on that?

Comment: Use your solution to answer the given example in the question.  Do not create a random scenario that seems to overlap in functionality and expect it to seem clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the wildcard filter as follows:

```
{"query": { "wildcard": {"lookup_field":"search_string*"}}}
```

Be sure to use `*`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command which uses the "starts with" paradigm:

```
db.customer.find({"customer_name" : { $regex : /^startswith/ }})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, someone is looking for an SQL *LIKE* kind of query for a key that holds an array of strings instead of a string, here it is:

```
db.users.find({"name": {$in: [/.*m.*/]}})
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are perfectly answering the questions about the core MongoDB query. But when using a pattern-based search query such as:

> {"keywords":{ "$regex": "^toron.*"}}

or

> {"keywords":{ "$regex": "^toron"}}

in a [Spring Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Spring_Boot) JPA repository query with @Query annotation, use a query something like:

```
@Query(value = "{ keyword : { $regex : ?0 }  }")
List<SomeResponse> findByKeywordContainingRegex(String keyword);
```

And the call should be either of:

```
List<SomeResponse> someResponseList =    someRepository.findByKeywordsContainingRegex("^toron");

List<SomeResponse> someResponseList =    someRepository.findByKeywordsContainingRegex("^toron.*");
```

But *never* use:

```
List<SomeResponse> someResponseList = someRepository.findByKeywordsContainingRegex("/^toron/");

List<SomeResponse> someResponseList =someRepository.findByKeywordsContainingRegex("/^toron.*/");
```

***An important point to note***: each time the **?0** field in **@Query** statement is replaced with a double quoted string. So forwardslash (/) should not be used in these cases! Always go for a pattern using double quotes in the searching pattern!! For example, use `"^toron" or "^toron.*"` over `/^toron/ or /^toron.*/`

Comment: for more details follow link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#regex-and-not

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use mongo JPA like query you should try this.

```
@Query("{ 'title' : { $regex: '^?0', $options: 'i' } }")
List<TestDocument> findLikeTitle(String title);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works too:

`db.getCollection('collection_name').find({"field_name": /^searched_value/})`