# How to query mongodb with “like” using the java api?

Tags: java, groovy, mongodb, find

this question is very similar to another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)

I basically want to use the mongodb version of the sql "like" '%m%' operator

but in my situation i'm using the java api for mongodb, while the other post is using mongodb shell

i tried what was posted in the other thread and it worked fine

```
db.users.find({"name": /m/})
```

but in java, i'm using the put method on the BasicDBObject and passing it into the find() method on a DBCollections object

```
BasicDBObject q = new BasicDBOBject();
q.put("name", "/"+m+"/");
dbc.find(q);
```

but this doesn't seem to be working.

anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You need to pass an instance of a Java RegEx ([java.util.regex.Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)):

```
BasicDBObject q = new BasicDBObject();
q.put("name",  java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(m));
dbc.find(q);
```

This will be converted to a MongoDB regex when sent to the server, as well as any RegEx flags.

Comment: +1 literally saved my sanity. I have been searching how to do some negative regex , as the $not operator does not except $regex

Answer (score 5):

You must first quote your text and then use the compile to get a regex expression:

```
q.put("name",  Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(m)));
```

Without using [`java.util.Pattern.quote()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409296/what-is-the-use-of-pattern-quote-method) some characters are not escaped.

e.g. using `?` as the `m` parameter will throw an exception.

Answer (score 4):

To make it case insensitive:

```
Document doc = new Document("name", Pattern.compile(keyword, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));
collection.find(doc);
```

Answer (score 1):

In spring data mongodb, this can be done as:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.limit(10);        
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("tagName").regex(tagName));
mongoOperation.find(query, Tags.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Document doc = new Document("name", Pattern.compile(keyword));
collection.find(doc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the actual answer, ( Executing the terminal query directly )

```
public void displayDetails() {
    try {
        // DB db = roleDao.returnDB();
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 5000);
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");
        db.eval("db.test.update({'id':{'$not':{'$in':[/su/]}}},{$set:{'test':'test3'}},true,true)", new Object[] {});
        System.out.println("inserted  ");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if(searchType.equals("employeeId"))
 {

query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(searchType).regex(java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(searchValue)));

employees = mongoOperations.find(query, Employee.class, "OfficialInformation");
}

Comment: Hi Sudheer Kumar Dara, welcome. Please consider adding an explanation and formating the code properly.