# What is the use of Pattern.quote method?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to understand `Pattern.quote` using the following code:

```
String pattern = Pattern.quote("1252343% 8 567 hdfg gf^$545");
System.out.println("Pattern is : "+pattern);
```

produces the output:

```
Pattern is : \Q1252343% 8 567 hdfg gf^$545\E
```

What are `\Q` and `\E` here? The documentation description says :

> Returns a literal pattern `String` for the specified `String`.
>
> This method produces a `String` that can be used to create a `Pattern` that would match the string `s` as if it were a literal pattern.
>
> Metacharacters or escape sequences in the input sequence will be given no special meaning.

But `Pattern.quote`'s return type is `String` and not a compiled `Pattern` object.

Why is this method required and what are some usage examples?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`\Q` means "start of literal text" (i.e. regex "open quote")
`\E` means "end of literal text" (i.e. regex "close quote")

Calling the `Pattern.quote()` method wraps the string in `\Q...\E`, which turns the text is into a regex *literal*. For example, `Pattern.quote(".*")` would match a dot and then an asterisk:

```
System.out.println("foo".matches(".*")); // true
System.out.println("foo".matches(Pattern.quote(".*"))); // false
System.out.println(".*".matches(Pattern.quote(".*"))); // true
```

The method's purpose is to not require the programmer to have to remember the special terms `\Q` and `\E` and to add a bit of readability to the code - regex is hard enough to read already. Compare:

```
someString.matches(Pattern.quote(someLiteral));
someString.matches("\\Q" + someLiteral + "\\E"));
```

Referring to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns a literal pattern String for the specified String.
>
> This method produces a String that can be used to create a Pattern that would match the string s as if it were a literal pattern.
>
> Metacharacters or escape sequences in the input sequence will be given no special meaning.

Comment: The correct equivalent to `someString.matches(Pattern.quote(someLiteral))` is actually `someString.matches("\\Q" + someLiteral.replace("\\E", "\\E\\\\E\\Q") + "\\E")`

Comment: @kbolino Rofl. And what about replacing "\\Q"?

Comment: @Andrew It handles that too: `"\\Q\\E".matches(Pattern.quote("\\Q\\E")) // true`.

Comment: Nein: "\\Q" becomes "\\Q\\Q\\E", no?

Comment: @Andrew yes, but regex is smart enough to know how to handle that: The quoted text is everything from a `\Q` (exclusive) to the next `\E` (exclusive), which may include any number of `\Q` sequences.

Answer (score 20):

The `Pattern.quote` method quotes part of a regex pattern to make regex interpret it as string literals.

Say you have some user input in your search program, and you want to regex for it. But this input may have unsafe characters so you can use

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(userInput));
```

This method does not quote a `Pattern` but, as you point out, wraps a `String` in regex quotes.

Answer (score 10):

`\Q` and `\E`, among all others, are thoroughly documented on the [java.util.regex.Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) Javadoc page. They mean "begin **Q**uote", "**E**nd quote" and demark a region where all the chars have the literal meaning. The way to use the return of `Pattern.quote` is to feed it to `Pattern.compile`, or any other method that accepts a pattern string, such as `String.split`.

Answer (score 7):

If you compile the String returned by `Pattern.quote`, you'll get a `Pattern` which matches the literal string that you `quote`d.

`\Q` and `\E` mark the beginning and end of the quoted part of the string.

Answer (score 7):

Regex collides frequently with normal strings. Say I want a regex to search for a certain string that is only known at runtime. How can we be sure that the string doesn't have regex meaning eg(`".*.*.*"`)? We quote it.

Comment: Indeed, one such example is when you want to replace the first occurrence of a substring, but String.replaceFirst takes a regex, when you want to pass a literal string.

Answer (score 0):

This method used to make the pattern treated as a sequence of literal characters.
This has the same effect as a **`PATTERN`.`LITERAL`** flag.