# How to search an string with [ character at the beginning using regular expression in sparql

Tags: java, regex, sparql

I have an String Like that:

```
String word ="[word";
```

I want to search this string as a substring to find Strings that contains these string. I have a query like that :

```
String Quert ="PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"
            + " SELECT ?class WHERE { ?class rdfs:label ?v ." +
            "FILTER regex(?v, \"" + word +"\", \"i\")}" ;
```

and when I run the program an error occur.

```
Regex: Pattern exception: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 6
```

So, how can I search this substring without producing this error?

edit: I use

```
Pattern.quote(word)
```

but I is producing another error:

```
Lexical error at line 1, column 118.  Encountered: "Q" (81), after : "\"\\"
```

Comment: Your `word` has `[` and no `]`. If you want to match a literal `[word` you need to `quote` the pattern with `Pattern.quote(word)`, or encose with `\Q` and `\E`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409296/what-is-the-use-of-pattern-quote-method.

Comment: You have to escape the `[` since it's part of REGEX families.