# How to split a String in Java with multiple delimiters utilizing a delimiter array?

Tags: java, string

What I want to do is take an input_string, as well as a char[] of delimiters and then split that input_string using all of the delimiters in that char[].

This is the code I have so far, but I have not found a way to utilize the char[] in the split function. If this isn't possible then I realize that I could have someone create a regex for a delimiter, but this is meant to be as simple as possible to change anything, so adding an extra delimiter would be as simple as adding it to the delimiters array.

```
public String[] stringSplit(char[] delimiters, String input_words) {
    String[] input_words_split = null;
    input_words_split = input_words.split(delimiters[0]);

    return input_words_split;

}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: What is the question? do you not want to iterate through the entire array?

Comment: "Could have someone create" - sorry, no. Regexps aren't that hard.

Comment: You could read the array and create a regular expression to pass to `String#split()` from it, making sure to escape any characters that need to be escaped.

Comment: `String splitRegex = Arrays.stream(new String(delimiters).split("")).map(Pattern::quote).collect(Collectors.joining("|")); return input_words.split(splitRegex);`

Comment: @shmosel, that is excellent.

Comment: Much simpler to just do this: `input_words_split = input_words.split("[" +  String.valueOf(delimiters) + "]");`

Comment: @neildo That will fail for special characters.

Comment: @shmosel true, if you need to use `]` or `[` or \ as delimiters. Otherwise, should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for being helpful, @shmosel, I've never really had experience with regexs and their syntax confuses me no matter how much I look at it. I have a couple of questions for you. When I print the `splitRegex` after I create it using the magic line of code above with the delimeters `{' ', 'a'}` it gives me the splitRegex = `\Q \E|\Qa\E`. Could you explain what the \Q and the \E mean?

Comment: @neildo I did a little digging, and it looks like your way will work if you enclose the delimiter block in `Pattern.quote()`: `return input_words.split("[" + Pattern.quote(String.valueOf(delimiters)) + "]");`

Comment: @shmosel, Boom! Even better.

Comment: @terrabl It's a form of escaping. It tells the regex engine not treat them as special characters. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15409296/1553851) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

In a recursive way :

```
 private static void split(String input, String[] separators, int index, List<String> output) {
        if(index == separators.length) {

            output.add(input);

        } else {
            final String separator = separators[index];

            for (String s : input.split(separator)) {
                split(s, separators, index + 1, output);
            }

        }
    }
```

How to use :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "te,st;rr;a,e";
        String[] separators = {",", ";"};

        List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();

        split(input, separators, 0, output);

        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

Output :

```
[te, st, rr, a, e]
```

Comment: How was this posted after the question was closed?

Comment: i think it was posted just before the question is being closed.

Comment: It was posted 20 minutes after.

Comment: Humm i'm not exactly sure :o