# Difference between Pattern.quote() and its String concatenation equivalent?

Tags: java, regex, string

Consider the following pieces of code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("[r.e.g.e.x]"));
```

and

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\Q" + "[r.e.g.e.x]" + "\\E");
```

As far as I know, they produce the exact same output. I know that the first is more easy to read, as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15409355/6714194). *But which approach is **better** or **faster**?*

Comment: Euhm `"\\Q[r.e.g.e.x]\\E"` will produce `"\\Q\\Q[r.e.g.e.x]\\E\\\\E\\Q\\E"`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Why?

Comment: because otherwise the `"\\E"` in the input would **not** be translated to literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement in the answer that:

> Calling the `Pattern.quote()` method wraps the string in `\Q...\E`, which turns the text is into a regex literal.

Is *strictly speaking* **not correct**. Indeed. Because that would give weird results if **`\Q` and `\E` are already in the original string**.

If you call for instance `Pattern.quote("\\Q[r.e.g.e.x]\\E")` it will produce `"\\Q\\Q[r.e.g.e.x]\\E\\\\E\\Q\\E"`.

As a result wrapping `"\\Q"` and `"\\E"` is obviously **incorrect** (for some *edge-cases*, I admit that). You better use `Pattern.quote` if you want to be *safe*.

The wrapping with `"\\Q"` and `"\\E"` you do yourself will be a bit faster (since you save on a method call, an `indexOf(..)` and an `if` statement in case there is no `"\\E"`), but usually you better *use libraries* since they tend to contain less bugs, and if there are bugs, these are resolved eventually.

You can find the [source code here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#Pattern.quote%28java.lang.String%29):

> ```
> public static String quote(String s) {
>     int slashEIndex = s.indexOf("\\E");
>     if (slashEIndex == -1)
>         return "\\Q" + s + "\\E";
>
>     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length() * 2);
>     sb.append("\\Q");
>     slashEIndex = 0;
>     int current = 0;
>     while ((slashEIndex = s.indexOf("\\E", current)) != -1) {
>         sb.append(s.substring(current, slashEIndex));
>         current = slashEIndex + 2;
>         sb.append("\\E\\\\E\\Q");
>     }
>     sb.append(s.substring(current, s.length()));
>     sb.append("\\E");
>     return sb.toString();
> }
> ```

So as long as **there is no `"\\E"`**, we are fine. But in the other case, we have to substitute every `"\\E"` with `"\\E\\\\E\\Q"`...