# Replace exact string with special characters and not the part of another substring

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I am trying to replace the substring from a string like:

`Sample string value '[1]T.1.v - Marriage Statement'!C10 and this`

The text to replace is `'[1]T.1.v - Marriage Statement'!C10` with some other string say `var1` so that the string becomes `Sample string value var1 and this`. The problem is there can be strings with values like `Sample string value '[1]T.1.v - Marriage Statement'!C101 and this` where the replacement should not work.
I was exploring the word boundary regex to limit the replacement:

```
String sample = "Value can be '[1]T.1.v - Marriage Statement'!C10 and this";
String a = sample.replaceAll("\\b'[1]T.1.v - Marriage Statement'!C10\\b", "var1");
System.out.println(a);
```

But this doesn't seem to replace the word at all. I tried simple string replace but that will replace the substring in `Sample string value '[1]T.1.v - Marriage Statement'!C101 and this` as well giving output as `Sample string value var11 and this` which is an error.

Any suggestions how can this be achieved?

Comment: Remove leading `\b` also you didn't escape brackets `[`, `]` and dots.

Comment: Actually the value '[1]T.1.v - Marriage Statement'!C10 is coming as a string variable at runtime.

Comment: So the code ideally is sample.replaceAll("\\b" + param +"\\b", "var1");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove leading `\b` then work with `\Q...\E` escape sequence to treat input string as literals:

```
String a = sample.replaceAll("\\Q" + param +"\\E\\b", "var1");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I arrived at the same answer using the lead by @dasblinkenlight but it was helpful to confirm it :)

Answer (score 1):

Single quote is *not* considered a word boundary, so the initial `\\b` anchor prevents the rest of the text from matching.

Moreover, your text itself has a significant number of special characters, so it should be [*quoted*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15409296/335858) with `\\Q` and `\\E`.

Here is a regex that fixes these shortcomings:

```
"(?<=\\s|^)\\Q'[1]T.1.v - Marriage Statement'!C10\\E(?=\\s|$)"
```

It replaces the initial `\\b` with `(?<=\\s|^)`, and the final `\\b` with `(?=\\s|$)` to allow for the target string to begin and end in non-word characters, such as quotes. Use of `\\Q` and `\\E` allows us to keep special characters in the rest of the target string unescaped.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/nwYrZn)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just have one small doubt. If the string expression has parentheses around the text to replace or has comma afterwards then it wont work right? Like  "Value can be ('[1]T.1.v - Marriage Statement'!C101) and this";

Comment: @SangramMohite This would not work for boundaries other than spaces and beginning/ending of the line. If you have a list of characters at which you would like to break the search, simply add them to the list, along with `\\s`.

Comment: FYI `(?<=\s|^)` == `(?<!\S)`

Comment: It lead me to the answer and got the same answer from @revo too!

String a = sample.replaceAll("\\Q" + "'[1]T.1.v - Marriage Statement'!C10" + "\\E\\b", "var1");

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! It has been helpful!

Comment: @SangramMohite Removing leading and/or trailing break marks lets you match parts of longer substrings. A better approach is to come up with an explicit list of characters that break a substring, and use them in your regex for lookaheads and lookbehinds.

Answer (score 0):

Escape brackets and dots

```
'\[1\]T\.1\.v - Marriage Statement'!C10
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

• change your `\\'` in your `replaceAll` to just `\'`

• change `replaceAll(...` to `replace(...` (See bottom of post)

It should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
    String sample = "Value can be '[1]T.1.v - Marriage Statement'!C10 and this";
    String a = sample.replace("\'[1]T.1.v - Marriage Statement\'!C10", "var1");
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Yielding the output:

```
Value can be var1 and this
```

using `replaceAll` is better if you are replacing a bunch of occurances of something, such as the letter A. `replace` is good for replacing something if it is just one instance.

Comment: I mentioned in the question. I tried this but the problem is that it would replace for substrings '[1]T.1.v - Marriage Statement'!C101 also which is unexpected.

Comment: I tried simple string replace but that will replace the substring in "Sample string value '[1]T.1.v - Marriage Statement'!C101 and this" as well giving output as Sample string value var11 and this which is an error.

Comment: I ran this exactly how it is in the post and it works fine. Your main problem was the `\\'` rather than `\'` in your replacement method(See bullet point 1).