# word boundary and pattern quote not working

Tags: java, regex, word-boundary

```
String haystack = "hey (( howdy";
haystack.matches(".*\\b\\Q((\\E\\b.*");
```

Line 2 should return true, but it returns false. Is this bug in Java, or am I doing it wrong?

Edit : What I am trying to achieve is see if an user input (complete word) is present in the `haystack`

Comment: unescaped `(`...

Comment: ^ this is your problem (previous comment)...

Comment: @Hitmands

Since it is wrapped by `\Q` `\E`, it doesn't require escaping.

Comment: @JorgeCampos

Since it is wrapped by `\Q` `\E`, it doesn't require escaping.

Comment: Never used \Q or \E before on java, are you sure that Java supports it? Tried without it?

Comment: @JorgeCampos https://stackoverflow.com/q/15409296/5455629 

If we try without \Q \E it throws exception about "unmatched parenthesis"

 Also please see my edit of question. Is there another way to achieve my goal?

Comment: It works fine for me here: `String test = "some text (( other text"; System.out.println(test.matches(".*\\(\\(.*"));` yields to true.

Comment: Probably because `((` is not a word. Try using space boundaries instead.

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: learn to use tools like [RegEx 101](http://regex101.com) before coming here.

Answer (score 2):

To do what you want you just need to search for the user input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "some text (( other text inside a stack";
    String userInput = "((";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*" + Pattern.quote(userInput) + ".*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    System.out.println(m.find());
}
```

The problem is that `((` is not a word, therefore it can't be matched when preceded and suffixed by `\b`

It prints:

```
true
```

Note: To fit in a program that can matches both. You will probably test first if the user input is a word if yes you use boundaries if not this above solution.

Comment: if user input is `((` It will throw exception

Comment: I think using space boundary as suggested by @shmosel along with start and end boundary would be easier `.matches(".*(^|\\s)" + Pattern.quote(keyword)+ "(\\s|$).*")`

Comment: Have you tested this, it wont work here. That's because `^` can not have anything before it. Also `$` can not have anything after it to work

Comment: @q126y - you have some very basic misconceptions about how regex works given your misuse of fundamental things like `^` and `$`.

Comment: @JorgeCampos is my sample program valid, or did I misunderstood what you were trying to say?

Comment: @JorgeCampos The user input is not at the start and it works https://ideone.com/m04z2K

Comment: Well it do works, though it is very strange. It shouldn't. It seems that in a regex when the mask `^` preceded by an `.*` can be valid if there is nothing to match that `.*`. That is new to me.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson `you have some very basic misconceptions about how regex works given your misuse of fundamental things like ^ and $` what? how?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it has something to do with the '\b' Word Boundary matching as it is implementation dependant according to this article: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Have you tried:

```
String haystack = "hey (( howdy";
haystack.matches(".*\\b \\Q((\\E \\b.*"));
```

Note the spaces before/after \b.