# ReplaceAll when it is not alpha characters

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I need to replace all the occurrences of a word in a String when it is between non alpha characters(digits, blankspaces...etc) or at the beginning or the end of the String for a $0. However, my Regex pattern does not seem to work when I use replaceAll.

I have tried several solutions which I found on the web, like Pattern.quote, but the pattern doesn't seem to work. However, it works perfectly on https://regexr.com/

```
public static final String REPLACE_PATTERN = "(?<=^|[^A-Za-z])(%s)(?=[^A-Za-z]|$)";

String patternToReplace = String.format(REPLACE_PATTERN, "a");

inputString = inputString.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(patternToReplace), "$0");
```

For example, with the string and the word "a":

```
a car4is a5car
```

I expect the output to be:

```
$0 car4is $05car
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change from `inputString.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(patternToReplace), "$0");` to `inputString.replaceAll(patternToReplace, "\\$0");`

I have tested with this code :

```
public static final String REPLACE_PATTERN = "(?<=^|[^A-Za-z])(%s)(?=[^A-Za-z]|$)";
String patternToReplace = String.format(REPLACE_PATTERN, "a");
inputString = inputString.replaceAll(patternToReplace, "\\$0");
System.out.println(inputString);
```

Output :

```
$0 car4is $05car
```

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

`Pattern.quote()` returns regex literal and everything in-between is [treated like a text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15409355/4581323).

You should use `Matcher` to replace all string occurrences. Besides that, as [@Donat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10533011/donat) pointed out, `$0` is treated like a regex variable, so you need to escape it.

```
inputString = Pattern.compile(patternToReplace).matcher(inputString).replaceAll("\\$0");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to replace the matching parts of the string with `"$0"`, you have to write it
`"\\$0"`. This is because `$0` has a special meaning: The matching string. So you replace the string by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are quoting the wrong thing. You should not quote the pattern. You should quote `"a"` - the part of the pattern that should be treated *literally*.

```
String patternToReplace = String.format(REPLACE_PATTERN, Pattern.quote("a"));
```

If you are never going to put anything other letters in the second argument of `format`, then you don't need to `quote` at all, because letters do not have special meaning in regex.

Additionally, `$` has special meaning when used as the replacement, so you need to escape it:

```
inputString = inputString.replaceAll(patternToReplace, "\\$0");
```