# MongoDB Tree find descendants Java

Tags: java, mongodb, tree

I have a tree like this in Mongo:

```
> db.data.find()
{ "_id" : "07c", "path" : null }
{ "_id" : "a", "path" : "07c,a" }
{ "_id" : "b", "data" : "{\"c\":\"olaC\",\"d\":\"olaD\"}", "path" : "07c,a,b" }
{ "_id" : "c", "c" : "{\"c\":\"olaC\",\"d\":\"olaD\"}", "path" : "07c,a,b,c" }
{ "_id" : "d", "d" : "{\"d\":\"olaD\"}", "data" : "{\"c\":\"olaC\",\"d\":\"olaD\"}", "path" : "07c,a,b,c,d" }
```

I would like to retrieve all descendants of b.

If I do this in the MongoDB console, I get the descendants fine:

```
> db.data.find({ path: /,b,/ } )
{ "_id" : "c", "c" : "{\"c\":\"olaC\",\"d\":\"olaD\"}", "path" : "07c,a,b,c" }
{ "_id" : "d", "d" : "{\"d\":\"olaD\"}", "data" : "{\"c\":\"olaC\",\"d\":\"olaD\"}",     "path" : "07c,a,b,c,d" }
```

but if I do this in Java:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("path", "/,"+array[i]+",/");
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);
while(cursor.hasNext()){
   System.out.println(cursor.next().toString());
}
```

From the debugger the query contains this: { "path" : "/,b,/"}

I get no descendants at all...Why doesn't this work?

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/

Comment: Try this one : query.put("path", Pattern.compile("/,"+array[i]+",/"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/../ is special in the MongoDB shell. It is not simply a string containing a regular expression, but something that is parsed by the shell and used as a regular expression.

To do this from Java, you would do something like:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("name", Pattern.compile(","+array[i]+","));
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);
while(cursor.hasNext()){
   System.out.println(cursor.next().toString());
}
```

See also: [How to query mongodb with “like” using the java api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608584/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like-using-the-java-api)

Comment: You and @Abhishek Kumar were very close. I did indeed have to turn into a pattern but no need to put the comas and slashes:
    query.put("path", Pattern.compile(array[i]));

This worked fine, thank you for the help.

Comment: You'd need the comma's if you want to make sure it matches to only parts, otherwise compile("c") would also match against "abcdef" and not just "b,c,d". I suggest you always have a , on either side of your path string elements.