# How to filter records from mongodb in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to skip some records from DB which has some string in Java(using BasicDBOject). Say for eg:

"description" is my field name in a collection called "comment"

I don't want the records which has "Test message" as part of the value in field "description".

Comment: That's going to be a brute force poorly performing query as it won't be able to use an index and instead will run the regex on every `description`.

Comment: The question has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608584/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like-using-the-java-api/5608625#5608625

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the documentation at http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/#getting-a-set-of-documents-with-a-query and http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/QueryBuilder.html#regex%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29, as you don't seem to have put in too much effort into researching this yourself. The code would look something like:

```
Mongo m = new Mongo();
m.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.SAFE);
DBCollection c = m.getDB("testdb").getCollection("collection");

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Test Message");
DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start().
        QueryBuilder.start("description").regex(pattern).get();
System.out.println(c.find(query).count());
```

Comment: This answer is now out of date with respect to the Java API version 3.4.1+.

Comment: Got many old answers from 2011 as well...