# How to use a generic filter in MongoDB?

Tags: java, regex, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

I have the following filter for my mongodb:

```
"{'shortname': '/.*LKH.*/'}"
```

I use it with the following java code:

```
  BasicQuery c = new BasicQuery(filter);
  Iterable<Hospital> hospitals = template.find(c,Hospital.class);
```

I am getting no results, because of the surounding ' at the regular expression. If i execute the filter without the '' around the regex, i get results in mongodb. I tried different verisons but could not succeed. The filter i´m appliying must be generic, so i cannot have some parsing.

Has someone an idea how i can use a generic filter for MongoDB with the MongoTemplate in Java - or how i have to write my filter?

Comment: You have to use regex patterns, have a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608584/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like-using-the-java-api

Comment: I´ve seen this answear but it's not what i´m looking for.
I want to be able to apply a string as a filter, so it might also be any other filter.

Comment: I've never used mongodb the way you use it. But maybe you want to try [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) like in `"{'shortname': {$regex: /.*LKH.*/}}"`

Answer (score 0):

Solution proposed by [Wolfgang Kluge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2693792/wolfgang-kluge):

> I've never used mongodb the way you use it. But maybe you want to try [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) like in 
> `"{'shortname': {$regex: /.*LKH.*/}}"`

Comment: hi, we used a quite strange solution back then.
We posted a javascript evaluation.
As it was just a uni-project with limited time at hand, we needed a quick solution, although i would never apply this solution in real world