# MongoDB Database, query with LIKE

Tags: mongodb, find, sql-like

I have a MongoDB, I can query the database with 'Country' that works fine. But I now want to also search on the field 'title' with free text. As with in SQL the WHERE title LIKE '%title%'

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("country", country);
query.put("title", %title%);
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
```

How would I do this with MongoDB?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like

Comment: How would I put this into my code? 
 
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(); 
query.put("country", country); 
query.put("title", /title/i); ???????????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query MongoDB with "like"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [regular expressions](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions)
In your case, `/title/i` should work (as MySQL like query is usually case-insensitive, /i denotes case-insensitive match)

Comment: Thanks! How would I put this into my code?

    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("country", country);
    query.put("title", /title/i); ???????????

Answer (score 0):

Use this 
this pattern is java regular expression

```
Pattern title = Pattern.compile("title");
BasicDBObject dbc=new BasicDBObject();
dbc.put("title", title );
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
```

This will work,.. try it

Answer (score 0):

if you got the keyword in variable...

```
Model.find( { FIELD_NAME : { $regex: KEYWORD, $options: 'i' }});
```

and if you got the keyword as just a string...

```
Model.find( { FIELD_NAME : /string/i });
```

should work like SELECT * FROM Model WHERE FIELD_NAME LIST = KEYWORD.

'i' toggles case-insensivity, so that you can search the word with no case exception.