# How to turn an user inputted value into a regexp without messing up with special characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, user-input, contains

I'm fiddling around with MongoDB and there is something I stumbled upon. I'd like to make a simple application in which the user can search all documents in a collection, getting the documents of which the key `username` contains a certain user inputted value.

For implementing "contains" it [appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like) a regular expression can be used. This works fine, but how can I convert user input into a regular expression? The problem is that simply doing ...

```
new RegExp(value);
```

... does not work because of special characters (like `(`, `[` etc.). This means the user cannot do a query containing `(` this way.

I thought escaping everything would do the job:

```
new RegExp(value.replace(/./g, function(x) {
    return "\\" + x;
});
```

... but it doesn't because some escaped characters are also special (e.g. `\d`), so this way non-special characters become special.

I'm a bit lost how I could turn a user inputted value into a regular expression. Or is there perhaps a better way of doing a query for all documents of which a key contains a certain user inputted value?

Comment: you could, of course, tell them that they need to provide a regular expression to search, or give the option, then tell them that `.`, `(`, and `[` need to be escaped (also `^`, and `$` and a few more I'm forgetting right now)

Comment: @Code Jockey: Let's pretend the target audience does not know about regular expressions and escaping. Even if the user did know these things, I'd need to escape server-side for security.

Answer (score 2):

**Implementation:**

Based on [this source](http://80.68.89.23/2006/Jan/20/escape/).

```
var oldText = "[hello, world :) ]";
var sre = new RegExp('(\\' + ['/', '.', '*', '+', '?', '|', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', '\\'].join('|\\') + ')', 'g');
var newText = oldText.replace(sre, '\\$1'); // "\[hello, world :\) \]"
```

**Further explanation:**

*sre* is a regular expression that is matching all possible special characters and is using parentheses so it can reference matched parts.

Incomplete *sre* example:

```
/(\/|\.|\\)/g
```

This will try to match for any of this characters: "/", "." and "\". Using then

```
text.replace(sre, '\\$1');
```

will escape every single matched character in text with "\". So it will replace "." with "\.", etc.