# Regex: Simple search regex?

Tags: regex, search

I need a regex which helps me searching through the database.

It should be able to do:

1. In word searching. Example: *ell* => Hello, Yello, Mellt, ....
2. Similar words: Example: gold => hold, golt, cost, ...

Is this possible to do with a regex?

If yes how does this regex look like?

Regards

Comment: What kind of database? What kind of language that allow you to search through the database?

Comment: Is this relevant? Here is the original thread. See the bottom. I just have to place a regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609697/expressjs-search-query-api As I know mongoosejs doesn't have a full-text-search, search option

Comment: It is relevant, since regex is not the same in all languages/tools. If we know the technology you are using, we might suggest something else better that can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Would usually be done via the `LIKE` operator with wildcards:

   ```
   WHERE column LIKE '%ell%'
   ```
2. Can be done with a string similarity measure, such as Levenshtein distance. [Here](http://kristiannissen.wordpress.com/2010/07/08/mysql-levenshtein/) is an implementation for MySQL as a Stored Procedure. However, for nearly every string similarity algorithm "gold" and "cost" are quite far apart.

Comment: Is there something like LIKE for mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

This is very general question. I can only recommend simple solution:

Lets have the first example you stated:

```
$your_root = "el"
```

then:

```
$string =~ /\w*$your_root\w*/
```

matches 'h **el** lo', 'y **el** lo' but also 'iafbi342b **el** erger64'