# Regular expression to match anything that doesn't contain '/'

Tags: regex

For example

```
Season           // matches
Season/Winter    // wont match
Season/Spring    // wont match
```

Comment: This regex is trivial. What have you tried?

Comment: @Michael And why don't you add an answer then?

Comment: @OlafDietsche Because it would be great practice for him/her to learn regex. Also, he/she didn't even show any work, so it seems like he didn't even attempt it and is just coming to us for a quick answer. Teach a man to fish, etc.

Comment: @Michael, Yeah you're probably right... I just use regular expressions so little that they drive me mad because I keep forgetting the systax.. Don't know if i'm the only one in this boat.

Comment: @Raymo The best way to figure out how to use `regex` is to experiment yourself. Here's a site that let's you see what your regex is actually doing: http://www.regex101.com/. This is also another good one: http://www.regexplanet.com/. But first, I would recommend reading through this entire site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really doubt you'd need a regular expression for that in any language, anyway:

```
^[^/]*$
```

http://regexr.com?339e2

You can usually use string search methods such as JavaScript's `indexOf` string method or PHP's `strpos` function to try to find `/`, most languages offer native string methods which are much faster and a better solution than regex, even more for something so simple.
**Edit:** For mongodb as OP's case, regex seems to be the most suitable solution though. I believe it should be more optimized than iterating through all records with another language's string function.

Comment: I'm need it for a php mongoDB query.  I think a regex is the only solution here.. I'm open to suggestions though.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought it could be a more specific use-case like that. `=]` I'll keep the note though so the other readers that simply look for a regex to match `/` in other languages will have that info.

Comment: @Raymo Looking through this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3305561/1331430), seems like regex is actually the only way for this.

Comment: It's also useful for a ruby gem's files, if you want to match only the `lib`, `bin`, and `test`/`spec`/`features` folders AND all files  in the root.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a *character class*.  These are the `[` and `]` characters.  inside, you specify the characters you are looking for.  You can also add the `^` character, to indicate a negated character class, where it contains anything BUT the one you've specified.  So, your regex is:

```
^[^/]*$
```

However, most string libraries have tools to look for a particular character.  For example, in C#, you can do:

```
if (! String.Contains("/")) { /* your logic here */ }
```