# How to query by substring in a MongoDB ODM

Tags: mongodb, symfony, dql, odm, database

I have this actual code

```
public function findCode($code_received)
{

    $pellicules =
            $this->createQueryBuilder()
            ->field('code_base')->equals($code_received)
            ->getQuery()
            ;

}
```

But sometimes my code received is inside my code_base, for example:

Code_received = Abata

Code_base = Abata23xiub

I tried to use the `in` instead of `equals` but I'm not having success. How could I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query mongodb with condition “like” in symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029684/how-to-query-mongodb-with-condition-like-in-symfony2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query MongoDB with "like"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)