# MongoDB index and non-index performance

Tags: mongodb, performance, search, indexing

I heard from the mongodb docs that

> For case sensitive regular expression queries, if an index exists for the field, then MongoDB matches the regular expression against the values in the index, which can be faster than a collection scan. Further optimization can occur if the regular expression is a “prefix expression”, which means that all potential matches start with the same string. This allows MongoDB to construct a “range” from that prefix and only match against those values from the index that fall within that range.

query:

```
db.getCollection('contacts').find({username: {$regex: 'an'}}).explain()
```

Here is the stats without indexing `username`

```
"cursor" : "BasicCursor",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 14234,
"nscannedObjects" : 107721,
"nscanned" : 107721,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 107721,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 107721,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 841,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 108,
"server" : "random-ubunto:3001",
"filterSet" : false
```

And stats with indexing `username`

```
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor username_1",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 14234,
"nscannedObjects" : 14234,
"nscanned" : 106898,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 14234,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 106898,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 835,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 142,
"indexBounds" : {
    "username" : [ 
        [ 
            "", 
            {}
        ], 
        [ 
            /an/, 
            /an/
        ]
    ]
},
"server" : "random-ubunto:3001",
"filterSet" : false
```

Yes i can see the difference of `nscannedObjects`. Thats very good but the question is why the `millis` of the indexing one are greater than without the indexing one. If we talk about the performance, `millis` should be vice versa. Currently

```
millis (Without Indexing) : 108
millis (With Indexing) : 142
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look on this:

[MongoDB, performance of query by regular expression on indexed fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501798/mongodb-performance-of-query-by-regular-expression-on-indexed-fields)

mentioned in above link:

For /Jon Skeet/ regex ,mongo will full scan the keys in the index then will fetch the matched documents, which can be faster than collection scan.

For /^Jon Skeet/ regex ,mongo will scan only the range that start with the regex in the index, which will be faster.

Comment: Yes i have already tried. But Not a big difference. It's `millis` are around 120-130. while without index its 100-110. Why?