# How to create index properly in MongoDB to search in entire one collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I a have collection named `people` and this collection have almost **100k** `documents`..

While I am a front-end dev, I don't know How can I boost my search performance.

I do search as below:

```
const phoneNumbers = [
   { "phone": { "$regex": `1` } },
   { "phone": { "$regex": `2` } },
   { "phone": { "$regex": `3` } },
   { "phone": { "$regex": `4` } },
   { "phone": { "$regex": `5` } },
   { "phone": { "$regex": `xxx` } },
   { "phone": { "$regex": `999` } },
   { "phone": { "$regex": `1000` } },
];


peopleCollection.find({$or: phoneNumbers}).toArray((error, matchedDocs)=> {
   // returning matched docs
});
```

As you can see the structure of my search what is your suggestions to create `index`?

Is that helpful to create **index** ?
If yes how Can I create a proper **index** ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501798/mongodb-performance-of-query-by-regular-expression-on-indexed-fields

Answer (score 0):

Indexing does not reduce the complexity of your search expression, rather it helps the database to find out the matched result faster(i.e. reduce the time complexity).

Here is how you can create indexing:

**db.collectionName.createIndex(key_name)**

The above one-line operation creates indexing on key **key_name**.

Comment: Please let me know how can I create it as you can see my code