# How to calculate the count of regex query results?

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a large MongoDB collection (approx. 30M records) and each item has an array of unique numbers consisting of 8 digits. Most of the time that array has only 1 element (1 number). I want to find out how many records the collection holds with numbers starting with 4, for example, so I query:

```
{ "numbers.number": /^4.*/i }
```

However, the query takes too long, last time it took 20 minutes before I interrupted the execution. So I wonder if there's a way to optimize the query. `numbers.number` is indexed. I also tried this one:

```
{ "numbers.number": /^4[0-9]{7}/}
```

still takes too long. Here's an example of the document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("some_id"), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2022-10-13T09:32:45.000+0000"), 
    "source" : {
        "created_at" : ISODate("2021-10-13T08:54:06.000+0000"), 
        "some_id" : NumberInt(234), 
        "another_id" : NumberInt(11)
    }, 
    "first_name" : "Test", 
    "last_name" : "Test", 
    "date_of_birth" : "1970-01-01", 
    "status" : "active", 
    "numbers" : [
        {
            "created_at" : ISODate("2022-11-13T09:32:45.000+0000"), 
            "number" : "40000005", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("some_id")
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Try to use [$elemMatch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

Comment: @Valijon can't use it with objects, see the example

Comment: `numbers` is an array, is it?

Comment: yes, but it's an array of objects, not numbers

Comment: Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hiAg2d3eei7)

Comment: @Valijon the `$elemMatch` does not require if there is only one property to match in array of object, he has to match just single property `number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression is costly for performance and speed even if it has an index or not, if you have data in the millions count,

This is a similar question, [MongoDB, performance of query by regular expression on indexed fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501798/mongodb-performance-of-query-by-regular-expression-on-indexed-fields)

I am not sure, *I have not compared and tested the performance.* but try just `^` sign without `.*`,

```
{ "numbers.number": /^4/ }
```

As per the additional note in [regex index use documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use) of MongoDB,

> Additionally, while `/^a/`, `/^a.*/`, and `/^a.*$/` match equivalent strings, they have different performance characteristics. All of these expressions use an index if an appropriate index exists; however, `/^a.*/`, and `/^a.*$/` are slower. `/^a/` can stop scanning after matching the prefix.

---

The second option, I would suggest if you know the range of the number you could just use `$gte` and `$lt` operator to find the specific series by specifying numbers,

```
{ 
  "numbers.number": {
    "$gte": "40000000",
    "$lt": "50000000"
  }
}
```

Third, you can check multiple ranges by using `$or` operator,

```
{ 
  "$or": [
    {
      "numbers.number": {
        "$gte": "4000000",
        "$lt": "5000000"
      }
    },
    {
      "numbers.number": {
        "$gte": "40000000",
        "$lt": "50000000"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

> **NOTE:**
>
> - try to execute this query in MongoDB shell
> - always use count functions, if you just need counts of the documents
>
>   - `db.coll.find({query}).count()`
>   - `db.coll.countDocuments({query})`

Comment: Thanks, the first option worked like a charm, the other two didn't. Also, is there an efficient way to specify the length too? Let's say I want to count all records with numbers that start with 4 and have exactly 8 digits.

Comment: There is no straight way, you have to use an aggregation expression operator condition using `$expr`, `$filter` and `$strLenCP`, is it one time process or functionality?

Comment: You can use range condition `{ "numbers.number": { "$gte": "40000000", "$lt": "50000000" } }`

Comment: It's a functionality, I use it frequently to generate new unique numbers.
I tried the range, but it works too slow.

Comment: There is no straight way, check this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bYW4XziKLFz), aggregation query might work not sure.