# MongoDB Full and Partial Text Search

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb, full-text-indexing

**Env:**

- MongoDB (3.2.0) with Mongoose

---

**Collection:**

- users

---

**Text Index creation:**

```
  BasicDBObject keys = new BasicDBObject();
  keys.put("name","text");

  BasicDBObject options = new BasicDBObject();
  options.put("name", "userTextSearch");
  options.put("unique", Boolean.FALSE);
  options.put("background", Boolean.TRUE);
  
  userCollection.createIndex(keys, options); // using MongoTemplate
```

---

**Document:**

- {"name":"LEONEL"}

---

**Queries:**

- `db.users.find( { "$text" : { "$search" : "LEONEL" } } )` => FOUND
- `db.users.find( { "$text" : { "$search" : "leonel" } } )` => FOUND (search caseSensitive is false)
- `db.users.find( { "$text" : { "$search" : "LEONÉL" } } )` => FOUND (search with diacriticSensitive is false)
- `db.users.find( { "$text" : { "$search" : "LEONE" } } )` => FOUND (Partial search)
- `db.users.find( { "$text" : { "$search" : "LEO" } } )` => NOT FOUND (Partial search)
- `db.users.find( { "$text" : { "$search" : "L" } } )` => NOT FOUND (Partial search)

Any idea why I get 0 results using as query "LEO" or "L"?

Regex with Text Index Search is not allowed.

```
db.getCollection('users')
     .find( { "$text" : { "$search" : "/LEO/i", 
                          "$caseSensitive": false, 
                          "$diacriticSensitive": false }} )
     .count() // 0 results

db.getCollection('users')
     .find( { "$text" : { "$search" : "LEO", 
                          "$caseSensitive": false, 
                          "$diacriticSensitive": false }} )
.count() // 0 results
```

---

**MongoDB Documentation:**

- [Text Search](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/text-search/)
- [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)
- [Text Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/)
- [Improve Text Indexes to support partial word match](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15090)

Comment: This question is related to partial search using a text index and not case sensitive search. @LucasCosta please don't tag this question as duplicated.

Comment: Did you tried `/LEO/i`? You can to use regex in search value in mongodb

Comment: @LucasCosta text index search does not allow regex.

Comment: Search without index: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48250561/557432

Answer (score 89, accepted):

As at MongoDB 3.4, the [text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/) feature is designed to support case-insensitive searches on text content with language-specific rules for stopwords and stemming. Stemming rules for [supported languages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/text-search-languages/) are based on standard algorithms which generally handle common verbs and nouns but are unaware of proper nouns.

There is no explicit support for partial or fuzzy matches, but terms that stem to a similar result may appear to be working as such. For example: "taste", "tastes", and tasteful" all stem to "tast". Try the [Snowball Stemming Demo](http://snowballstem.org/demo.html) page to experiment with more words and stemming algorithms.

Your results that match are all variations on the same word "LEONEL", and vary only by case and diacritic. Unless "LEONEL" can be stemmed to something shorter by the rules of your selected language, these are the only type of variations that will match.

If you want to do efficient partial matches you'll need to take a different approach. For some helpful ideas see:

- [Efficient Techniques for Fuzzy and Partial matching in MongoDB](http://web.archive.org/web/20190714185232/http://ilearnasigoalong.blogspot.com/2013/10/efficient-techniques-for-fuzzy-and.html) by John Page
- [Efficient Partial Keyword Searches](https://web.archive.org/web/20170609122132/http://jam.sg/blog/efficient-partial-keyword-searches/) by James Tan

There is a relevant improvement request you can watch/upvote in the MongoDB issue tracker: [SERVER-15090: Improve Text Indexes to support partial word match](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15090).

Comment: Now there is a better way. Checkout Atlas Search in the free tier to improve efficiency: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/atlas-search/

Comment: Sorry, but atlas is just a different solution. Of course, we could use elastic and it's even better for those, who need self-hosting solutions. But anyway, atlas does not fix inability of MongoDB to make substring searches...

Answer (score 27):

Without creating index, we could simply use:

`db.users.find({ name: /<full_or_partial_text>/i})` (case insensitive)

Comment: Upvoted, and it works with [aqp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/api-query-params). Thanks !

Comment: `new RegExp(string, 'i')` for anyone who needs dynamic string search

Comment: how do i set a variable in there?

Comment: Be aware that this is not efficient and scalable as the search is not over an indexed field, for large tables this will be slow.

Comment: this just searches in the "name" column

Answer (score 25):

As Mongo currently does not supports partial search by default...

I created a simple static method.

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, default: '', trim: true },
    body: { type: String, default: '', trim: true },
});

PostSchema.index({ title: "text", body: "text",},
    { weights: { title: 5, body: 3, } })

PostSchema.statics = {
    searchPartial: function(q, callback) {
        return this.find({
            $or: [
                { "title": new RegExp(q, "gi") },
                { "body": new RegExp(q, "gi") },
            ]
        }, callback);
    },

    searchFull: function (q, callback) {
        return this.find({
            $text: { $search: q, $caseSensitive: false }
        }, callback)
    },

    search: function(q, callback) {
        this.searchFull(q, (err, data) => {
            if (err) return callback(err, data);
            if (!err && data.length) return callback(err, data);
            if (!err && data.length === 0) return this.searchPartial(q, callback);
        });
    },
}

export default mongoose.models.Post || mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema)
```

How to use:

```
import Post from '../models/post'

Post.search('Firs', function(err, data) {
   console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: How can I return a data from the Post.search()?

Comment: @LeventeOrbán promises! I'll put an answer below.

Comment: More information: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/index.html

Comment: @RicardoCanelas is there a way to add an index on a subdocument field? also what if a field is an array?

Comment: Great answer! Was wondering if this works with async/await function as well. Just tried it, and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Let's talk about performance.. what is the time taken if I have 1 million records.

Comment: Thx ! How to get score weight ?

Comment: great answer, but how do you handle diacritics for the partial search? :))

Answer (score 20):

If you want to use all the benefits of MongoDB's full-text search AND want partial matches (maybe for auto-complete), the n-gram based approach mentioned by Shrikant Prabhu was the right solution for me. Obviously your mileage may vary, and this might not be practical when indexing huge documents.

In my case I mainly needed the partial matches to work for just the `title` field (and a few other short fields) of my documents.

I used an edge n-gram approach. What does that mean? In short, you turn a string like `"Mississippi River"` into a string like `"Mis Miss Missi Missis Mississ Mississi Mississip Mississipp Mississippi Riv Rive River"`.

Inspired by [this code](https://github.com/gengen1988/edge-ngrams/blob/master/index.js) by Liu Gen, I came up with this method:

```js
function createEdgeNGrams(str) {
    if (str && str.length > 3) {
        const minGram = 3
        const maxGram = str.length
        
        return str.split(" ").reduce((ngrams, token) => {
            if (token.length > minGram) {   
                for (let i = minGram; i <= maxGram && i <= token.length; ++i) {
                    ngrams = [...ngrams, token.substr(0, i)]
                }
            } else {
                ngrams = [...ngrams, token]
            }
            return ngrams
        }, []).join(" ")
    } 
    
    return str
}

let res = createEdgeNGrams("Mississippi River")
console.log(res)
```

Now to make use of this in Mongo, I add a `searchTitle` field to my documents and set its value by converting the actual `title` field into edge n-grams with the above function. I also create a `"text"` index for the `searchTitle` field.

I then exclude the `searchTitle` field from my search results by using a projection:

```
db.collection('my-collection')
  .find({ $text: { $search: mySearchTerm } }, { projection: { searchTitle: 0 } })
```

Comment: In my opinion this is the best solution so far, a shame mongo doesn't have ngram out of the box.

Comment: It returns inaccurate results though.. For example, "Large" would include: "Grayson Lars". Honestly Mongo is completely useless for text search, might as well use a side database like ElasticSearch.

Comment: @OliverDixon Really? That's crazy. Why would `large` include `Grayson Lars`? Is it considering that a phonetic match?

Comment: @JohannesFahrenkrug I have no idea, but that's what our test data was showing based on the n-grams approuch :-/

Answer (score 6):

I wrapped @Ricardo Canelas' answer in a mongoose plugin here [on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-partial-full-search)

Two changes made:
- Uses promises
- Search on any field with type `String`

Here's the important source code:

```
// mongoose-partial-full-search

module.exports = exports = function addPartialFullSearch(schema, options) {
  schema.statics = {
    ...schema.statics,
    makePartialSearchQueries: function (q) {
      if (!q) return {};
      const $or = Object.entries(this.schema.paths).reduce((queries, [path, val]) => {
        val.instance == "String" &&
          queries.push({
            [path]: new RegExp(q, "gi")
          });
        return queries;
      }, []);
      return { $or }
    },
    searchPartial: function (q, opts) {
      return this.find(this.makePartialSearchQueries(q), opts);
    },

    searchFull: function (q, opts) {
      return this.find({
        $text: {
          $search: q
        }
      }, opts);
    },

    search: function (q, opts) {
      return this.searchFull(q, opts).then(data => {
        return data.length ? data : this.searchPartial(q, opts);
      });
    }
  }
}

exports.version = require('../package').version;
```

### Usage

```
// PostSchema.js
import addPartialFullSearch from 'mongoose-partial-full-search';
PostSchema.plugin(addPartialFullSearch);

// some other file.js
import Post from '../wherever/models/post'

Post.search('Firs').then(data => console.log(data);)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a variable to store the string or value to be searched:

It will work with the Regex, as:

```
{ collection.find({ name of Mongodb field: new RegExp(variable_name, 'i') }
```

Here, the I is for the ignore-case option

Comment: I am using Monk and collection is just the db.get() function, to connect to the database

Answer (score 2):

The quick and dirty solution, that worked for me: use text search first, if nothing is found, then make another query with a regexp. In case you don't want to make two queries - `$or` works too, but [requires all fields in query to be indexed](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#restrictions).

Also, you'd better not to use case-insensitive rx, because [it can't rely on indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use). In my case I've made lowercase copies of used fields.

Answer (score 2):

Good n-gram based approach for fuzzy matching is explained here
(Also explains how to score higher for Results using prefix Matching)
https://medium.com/xeneta/fuzzy-search-with-mongodb-and-python-57103928ee5d

Note : n-gram based approaches can be storage extensive and mongodb collection size will increase.

Answer (score 1):

I create an additional field which combines all the fields within a document that I want to search.  Then I just use regex:

```
user = {
    firstName: 'Bob',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    address: {
        street: 'First Ave',
        city: 'New York City',
        }
    notes: 'Bob knows Mary'
}

// add combined search field with '+' separator to preserve spaces
user.searchString = `${user.firstName}+${user.lastName}+${user.address.street}+${user.address.city}+${user.notes}`

db.users.find({searchString: {$regex: 'mar', $options: 'i'}})
// returns Bob because 'mar' matches his notes field

// TODO write a client-side function to highlight the matching fragments
```

Answer (score 0):

**full/partial search in MongodB for a "pure" Meteor-project**

I adpated flash's code to use it with Meteor-Collections and simpleSchema but without mongoose (means: remove the use of `.plugin()`-method and `schema.path` (altough that looks to be a simpleSchema-attribute in flash's code, it did not resolve for me)) and returing the result array instead of a cursor.

Thought that this might help someone, so I share it.

```
export function partialFullTextSearch(meteorCollection, searchString) {

    // builds an "or"-mongoDB-query for all fields with type "String" with a regEx as search parameter
    const makePartialSearchQueries = () => {
        if (!searchString) return {};
        const $or = Object.entries(meteorCollection.simpleSchema().schema())
            .reduce((queries, [name, def]) => {
                def.type.definitions.some(t => t.type === String) &&
                queries.push({[name]: new RegExp(searchString, "gi")});
                return queries
            }, []);
        return {$or}
    };

    // returns a promise with result as array
    const searchPartial = () => meteorCollection.rawCollection()
        .find(makePartialSearchQueries(searchString)).toArray();

    // returns a promise with result as array
    const searchFull = () => meteorCollection.rawCollection()
        .find({$text: {$search: searchString}}).toArray();

    return searchFull().then(result => {
        if (result.length === 0) throw null
        else return result
    }).catch(() => searchPartial());

}
```

This returns a Promise, so call it like this (i.e. as a return of a async [Meteor-Method](https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html) `searchContact` on serverside).
It implies that you attached a [simpleSchema](https://github.com/aldeed/simpl-schema) to your collection before calling this method.

```
return partialFullTextSearch(Contacts, searchString).then(result => result);
```

Answer (score -5):

```
import re

db.collection.find({"$or": [{"your field name": re.compile(text, re.IGNORECASE)},{"your field name": re.compile(text, re.IGNORECASE)}]})
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written

Comment: thanks, using a regex like you show is working for pymongo