# How can I integrate MongoDB with Apache Lucene?

Tags: java, windows, mongodb, lucene

Is there any way to integrate Apache Lucene with MongoDB?
I have MongoDB database, I'm working on a Java project, I need an efficient partial-text searching on specific fields of a Collection; It seems like Mongodb Full-Text search is efficient but, It doesn't support partial search, also I need auto completion, I want to make the front-end Light and I want to do this autocomplete functionality in the back-end. Any better suggestion will be accepted, that is  better solutions. I'm new to this project. Hopping a soon reply, Thanks.

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833817/mongodb-full-and-partial-text-search)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I went through these docs before, still its missing the auto-complete, By referring many answers I have arrived in a conclusion that it will be better to use MongoDB along with other search engines like elasticsearch, Solr, or Lucene. Lucene is in Java so I chose lucene. please share your thoughts about this, It would be great for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Now there's [MongoDB Atlas Full-Text Search](https://www.mongodb.com/atlas/full-text-search) (currently in beta) that uses Apache Lucene as a backend.

A wide range of query operators are supported — everything from wildcard and fuzzy search to boolean and compound queries. Process text using linguistic rules with language analyzers, implement sophisticated scoring, and improve the user experience with highlighted snippets.

The requirements are: MongoDB Atlas cluster tier M30+, and running MongoDB v4.2+

See [MongoDB Atlas: Full Text Search documentation page](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/full-text-search/) and [Tutorial: Create and Query a FTS Index](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/full-text-search/tutorial/) for more information.