# MongoDB aggregate only working with exact string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas-search

I am trying to implement a search feature to MongoDB and this is the aggregate pipeline I am using:

```
[
    {
        '$search': {
            'text': {
                'query': 'albus', 
                'path': [
                    'first_name', 'email', 'last_name'
                ]
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$project': {
            '_id': 1, 
            'first_name': 1, 
            'last_name': 1
        }
    }, {
        '$limit': 5
    }
]
```

The command returns documents that contain only exactly `albus` or `Albus`, but return nothing for queries like `alb`, `albu`, etc. In the demo video I watched here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=8&v=kZ77X67GUfk, the instructor was able to search based on substring.

The search index I am currently using is the default dynamic one.
How would I need to change my command?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833817/mongodb-full-and-partial-text-search) answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [autocomplete](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/autocomplete/#autocomplete-ref) feature, so your query will look like this:

```
{
    $search: {
      "autocomplete": {
            'query': 'albus', 
            'path': [
               'first_name', 'email', 'last_name'
            ]
      }
   }
}
```

Mind you both `first_name`, `email` and `last_name` need to be mapped as [autocomplete type](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/index-definitions/#autocomplete) so a name like `albus` will be indexed as `a`, `al`, `alb`, `albu`, `albus`. Obviously this will vastly increase your index size.

Another thing to consider is tweaking the `maxGrams` and `tokenization` parameters. this will allow very long names to still work as expected and if you want to allow substring match like `lbu` matching `albus`.

Comment: Where would the maxGrams and tokenization parameters come into play?

Comment: When you define your mapping, you define those there to set the behaviour of the index. this can't be done dynamically as the tokens have to be created first.

Comment: Alright I have it setup so that it works with `alb`, `albu`, etc, but the `autocomplete` key only allows one field for the `path` key. Is there another way to handle this so that multiple fields can be queried?