# mongoDB prefix wildcard: fulltext-search ($text) find part with search-string

Tags: mongodb, wildcard

I have mongodb with a `$text-Index` and elements like this:

```
{
   foo: "my super cool item"
}
{
   foo: "your not so cool item"
}
```

If i do search with

```
mycoll.find({ $text: { $search: "super"} })
```

i get the first item (correct).

But i also want to search with "uper" to get the fist item - but if i try:

```
mycoll.find({ $text: { $search: "uper"} })
```

I dont get any results.

My Question:
If there is a way to use $text so its finds results with a part of the searching string? (e.g. like `'%uper%'` in `mysql`)

**Attention: I dont ask for a regex only search - i ask for a regex-search within a $text-search!**

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's not possible to do it with `$text` operator.

Text indexes are created with the terms included in the string value or in an array of strings and the search is based in those indices.

You can only group terms on a phrase but not take part of them.

Read [`$text` operator reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) and [text indexes description](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/).

Comment: Sure you can. See my answer.

Comment: Not with $text operator and text indexes.

Comment: Live from the docs: "If an index exists for the field, then MongoDB matches the regular expression against the values in the index, which can be faster than a collection scan."

Comment: As I said, not with $text operator.

Comment: I'd appreciate a documentation link or the output of an according `explain()` method.

Comment: Back to that topic after 2 years. Did anything change? I mean, no way to perform a substring matching with a `$text` operator? @MarkusWMahlberg I confirm the answer of @francadaval. You can use regex to search for partial matching, but the performance is not good, even with an index which prevents COLLSCAN. :(

Comment: He's saying you cannot do it, how is this the correct solution?

Comment: It's the correct answer not the correct solution since there isn't a solution using `$text`.

Comment: what is solution for this. I want both full text search functionality and partial search

Comment: @Markus W Mahlberg answer below is the right one. You can use regexp.

Comment: Cant we use regex for this ?

Answer (score 18):

The best solution is to use both a text index and a regex.
The index will provide excellent speed performances but won't match as many documents as a regex.
The regex will allow a fallback in case the index doesn't return enough results.

```js
db.mycoll.createIndex({ foo: 'text' });
db.mycoll.createIndex({ foo: 1 });
db.mycoll.find({
  $or: [
    { $text: { $search: 'uper' } },
    { foo: { $regex: 'uper' } }
  ]
});
```

For even better performances (but slightly different results), use `^` inside the regex:

```js
db.mycoll.find({
  $or: [
    { $text: { $search: 'uper' } },
    { foo: { $regex: '^uper' } }
  ]
});
```

Comment: The above solution doesn't work. Throwing an error: No query solutions

Comment: Removed an extra foo after collection name. Should work now!

Comment: the regex search would also find those results that text search finds... isn't this better with just regex search??

Comment: @user1955934 You will want to use a text search to speed up your query, since foo will be matched against an index. Consider the regex as a plan B in case you can't find enough results matching your index.

Comment: Ensure you have both indexes if it gives you 'No query solutions' exceptions

Comment: Do we have something similar that could work with aggregations as well?

Answer (score 15):

What you are trying to do in your second example is prefix wildcard search in your collection `mycoll` on field `foo`. This is not something the textsearch feature is designed for and it is not possible to do it with `$text` operator. [This behaviour](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#text-query-operator-behavior) does not include wildcard prefix search on any given token in the indexed field. However you can alternatively perform regex search as others suggested. Here is my walkthrough:

```
>db.mycoll.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53add9364dfbffa0471c6e8e"), "foo" : "my super cool item" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53add9674dfbffa0471c6e8f"), "foo" : "your not so cool item" }
> db.mycoll.find({ $text: { $search: "super"} })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53add9364dfbffa0471c6e8e"), "foo" : "my super cool item" }
> db.mycoll.count({ $text: { $search: "uper"} })
0
```

The `$text` operator supports search for a single word, search for one or more words or search for phrase. The kind of search you wish is not supported

The regex solution:

```
> db.mycoll.find({foo:/uper/})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53add9364dfbffa0471c6e8e"), "foo" : "my super cool item" }
>
```

The answer to your final question: to do mysql style `%super%` in mongoDB you would most likely have to do:

```
db.mycoll.find( { foo : /.*super.*/ } );
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I want to use the $text-feature because of "Text Score" and Language-Fields. 

But i understand form @rancadaval answer that $text only work with strings.

Comment: @user3351722 yes, with `$text` you can search for a word, a list of words or phrases. I updated the answer as well.

Comment: So how do you deal with search on multiple fields?

Answer (score 12):

It should work with `/uper/`.

See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/ for details.

**Edit:**

As per request in the comments:

The solution wasn't necessarily meant to actually give what the OP *requested*, but what he needed to solve the problem.

Since `$regex` searches don't work with text indices, a simple regex search over an indexed field should give the expected *result*, though not using the requested *means*.

Actually, it is pretty easy to do this:

```js
db.collection.insert( {foo: "my super cool item"} )
db.collection.insert( {foo: "your not so cool item"})
db.collection.ensureIndex({ foo: 1 })
db.collection.find({'foo': /uper/})
```

gives us the expected result:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("557f3ba4c1664dadf9fcfe47"), "foo" : "my super cool item" }
```

An added explain shows us that the index was used efficiently:

```js
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "test.collection",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "foo" : /uper/
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "filter" : {
                    "foo" : /uper/
                },
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "foo" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "foo_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "foo" : [
                        "[\"\", {})",
                        "[/uper/, /uper/]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        // skipped
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

To make a long story short: No, you can not reuse a `$text` index, but you can do the query efficiently. Like written in [Implement auto-complete feature using MongoDB search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892947/implement-auto-complete-feature-using-mongodb-search) , one could probably be even more efficient by using a map/reduce approach, eliminating redundancy and unnecessary stop words from the indices, at the cost of being not real time any more.

Comment: That's the `$regex` operator, which is not what OP asked about. It seems the `$text` operator does not support wildcards.

Comment: @zjm555: Well, it might be a solution to OPs problem in the first place. That's what is called "creative problem solving" and might be worth a try. ;)

Comment: Would like to know the reason for down voting. Did I miss something?

Comment: $search operator doesnt support regex. It only supports string which doesn't do a substring search on indexed fields. That's why it doesn't work. I tried it so you might as well should once to verify your answer

Comment: Can you please include an example in your answer?

Comment: This query doesn't use index efficiently, whole collection has to be scanned in worst scenario. Use `explain('executionStats')` and find out yourself... or just look at the index bounds in your answer. Such index is efficient only if you query for a prefix.

Comment: Also: this can only work "properly" with single field indexes. If you have index on `{foo: "text", bar: "text"}` and want to search in both of them you have to use `.find({$text: {$search: query}})` and then your answer won't work.

Answer (score 3):

As francadaval said, text index is searching by terms but if you combine `regex` and `text-index` you should be good.

```
mycoll.find({$or: [ 
  { 
    $text: {
      $search: "super"
    }
  },
  {
    'column-name': {
      $regex: 'uper',
      $options: 'i'
  }
]})
```

Also, make sure that you have normal index applied to the column other than text index.

Comment: it didn't work on mongo 3.2 . Which version did you test this query ?

Comment: 3.2.x, you need to create text index before you can use it, https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-text/#create-text-index

Comment: Not working for me. Getting error:         Error: error: {
 "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $regex",
 "code" : 2
}

Comment: Even if that worked, the input that we have is "uper". There is no way to guess "super" from "uper". This solution doesn't match the problem.

Comment: 1. `}` missing before `]`.  
2. Failed to produce a solution for TEXT under OR-other non-TEXT clauses under OR have to be indexed as well

Comment: Is there any solutions for search value like this `super cool`

Comment: Omg, what kind of indentation/formatting is this... Fixing.

Comment: I think regex case insensitive queries can't use indexes as per official docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use

Answer (score 1):

if you go with regex you can achieve search for "super cool" but not "super item", to achieve both request do an or request with $text and $regex for the search term.

make sure you index both text indexing and normal indexing to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could have achieved is as-

```
db.mycoll.find( {foo: { $regex :  /uper/i  } })
```

Here 'i' is an option, denotes case-insensitive search