# How to search full or partial match with first name and last name in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

How to search full or partial match with first name and last name in mongodb?
I tried using this,

```
{"name":{ $regex: str, $options: 'i'}}
```

But it is only for full match of the string.
Can I use regex for partial match?

Comment: What is the regex you are using to search?

Comment: str is a name "John Test"

Comment: `str` should be a Regex, not the actual string. MongoDB  uses Perl compatible regular expressions. Refer http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html to create regex which satisfies your need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of search better to create **text index**. mongo shell command to create [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-text/#create-text-index) for name field.

```
db.colectionName.createIndex( { name: "text" } );
```

then you can search using `$text` and  `$search`

```
var text = 'John Test''
db.collectionName.find({ $text: { $search: text  } });
```

for this query you will get if `name` contain **john** or **test** and this is *case insensitive*

Comment: I tried this. No error. There is no list displayed after I searched.

Comment: have you created `text index` and  can you show your code that you have tried ? @JohnArellano

Answer (score 0):

I have to do this for my project, how does this work for you? `{"name":new RegExp('^'+name, 'i')}` you may need to encode the string first `str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');`

Comment: @JohnArellano Escape the regex characters, otherwise input with regex symbols such as `*` or `.` will be parsed as regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{'name': {'$regex': '.*str.*', $options: 'i'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have responded to similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41249257/1517277), combining text index and regex pattern makes it work nicely. Note, text index is searching by terms so if you try to search for `padavan` by supplying `pad` you won't get what you are expecting having only `text` index in place.