# MongoDb text search returns empty result

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

There is this collection

```
rs-ds123584:PRIMARY> db.Task.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c11f7a00d12b470d915e609"), "description" : "xxxx", "id" : ObjectId("5c11f7a00d12b470d915e609") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c12001e71795080bd2c246c"), "description" : "safdsgsd", "assignedUserId" : ObjectId("5c0d073f48629a2a01e6a15a") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c1200431cb44181e8719ff1"), "description" : "safdsgsd", "assignedUserId" : ObjectId("5c0d073f48629a2a01e6a15a") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c1201d6c37ece8562fdfb5d"), "description" : "safdsgsd", "assignedUserId" : ObjectId("5c0d073f48629a2a01e6a15a") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c120207d57361862cb54f48"), "description" : "safdsgsd", "assignedUserId" : ObjectId("5c0d073f48629a2a01e6a15a") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c120313715d4a89bbc330e0"), "description" : "safdsgsd", "assignedUserId" : ObjectId("5c0d073f48629a2a01e6a15a") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c12054f715d4a89bbc330e1"), "description" : "safdsgsd", "assignedUserId" : ObjectId("5c0d073f48629a2a01e6a15a") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c1205c5715d4a89bbc330e2"), "description" : "XXXXXX", "assignedUserId" : ObjectId("5c0d073f48629a2a01e6a15a") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c1205e9d132ec8f5fc94d86"), "description" : "safdsgsd", "assignedUserId" : ObjectId("5c0d073f48629a2a01e6a15a") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c1206d8d132ec8f5fc94d87"), "description" : "safdsgsd", "assignedUserId" : ObjectId("5c0d073f48629a2a01e6a15a") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c120cc71b0bc59d11a70232"), "description" : "safdsgsd", "assignedUserId" : ObjectId("5c0d073f48629a2a01e6a15a") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c120d7ceeeeab9f01a26b0e"), "description" : "stretert", "assignedUserId" : ObjectId("5c0d073f48629a2a01e6a15a") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c120dc609060aa06968668c"), "description" : "nw", "assignedUserId" : ObjectId("5c0d073f48629a2a01e6a15a"), "creatorUserId" : ObjectId("5c0f8c4a7a89e6a8b7f4bed8") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c120f516c64a2a498c9255e"), "description" : "safsa", "assignedUserId" : ObjectId("5c0d073f48629a2a01e6a15a") }
```

It got indexes like this

```
rs-ds123584:PRIMARY> db.Task.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "ev.Task"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_fts" : "text",
            "_ftsx" : 1
        },
        "name" : "$**_text",
        "ns" : "ev.Task",
        "weights" : {
            "$**" : 1
        },
        "default_language" : "english",
        "language_override" : "language",
        "textIndexVersion" : 3
    }
]
```

But when doing a text search like this

```
rs-ds123584:PRIMARY> db.Task.find({$text:{$search: 'saf'}})
rs-ds123584:PRIMARY> db.Task.find({$text:{$search: 'x'}})
```

The response is always empty array.
What's the problem here?
It seems everything here is according to the docs
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343156/mongodb-prefix-wildcard-fulltext-search-text-find-part-with-search-string

Comment: you need to use `$regex` for this use case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongoDB prefix wildcard: fulltext-search ($text) find part with search-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343156/mongodb-prefix-wildcard-fulltext-search-text-find-part-with-search-string)