# advance search text box in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, search, nosql

I work on an online search project. Its database is MongoDB
I want to make a search textbox that works like:
if I want to search for a book
The author is "Joe"
The title is "my book" 
and publisher is "tia"

I want to type in the search textbox: "joe my book tia" or "tia jo book"

> so I will get a result for it.

Author, Title, and publisher are in the JSON on the MongoDB

can Some Body Help me?

This is a Sample about JSON:

> {   "Author": [
>       {
>         "id": "1",
>         "name": "Joe",
>         "last name": "Jeff"
>       },
>       {
>         "id": "1",
>         "name": "Lama",
>         "last name": "moon"
>       }   ],   "Title": "My Book",   "Publisher": "tia" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB provides [text indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/#text-operator) to support text search queries on string content. text indexes can include any field whose value is a string or an array of string elements.

In your case you can run the following in a mongo shell to allow text search over the Author name and Publisher fields:

```
db.test.createIndex({ 'Author.name': 'text', 'Author.last_name': 'text', Publisher: 'text'})
```

Then you could use the following query to find all documents containing any terms from the list "joe", "my", "book" and "tia".

```
db.test.find({ $text: { $search: "joe my book tia" } })
```

Comment: Okay that what I want but also I need to put on the search for the name "Sara"
"Sar" the search will find each indexed name with "Sar*"

Comment: It's not posible to do it with $text operator.
Text indexes are created with the terms included in the string value or in a strings array and the search is based in those idexes.
You can only group terms on a pharse but not take part of them.
for reference please read this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343156/mongodb-prefix-wildcard-fulltext-search-text-find-part-with-search-string