# How to get all the documents of the indexed fields with text-search?

Tags: regex, mongodb, text-search

I was looking for a way to get all the documents of indexed-field through mongodb text-search.

Though I tried approaches of using regular expressions given below but it's not working. Please suggest.

```
db.docs.find( { $text: { $search: ".*" } } )
```

Comment: Please find from this link answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343156/mongodb-prefix-wildcard-fulltext-search-text-find-part-with-search-string

Comment: @Ravi that is a workaround approach using either textsearch or regex search. But I am looking for solution which is exclusive to textsearch