# How to count objects with a particular day in mongodb and php

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a date saved as a string like this `tdate:"2016-11-26 2:23:11"` in mongodb. I want to count all objects which have this date `2016-11-26`.
This is how I am trying to do using `php` but have no luck.

date_authenticated has this format `"Y-m-d H:i:s"` while I want to get all objects by `day` which should have this format `"Y-m-d"`

```
function count_auth($tdate) {
  $collection = 'mycollection';
  return $this->db->{$collection}->count(array('date_authenticated' => $tdate));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have saved the date as a string you can find entries with MongoRegex like described in [PHP mongo find field starts with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872398/php-mongo-find-field-starts-with). In your case it should be something like:

```
$startsWithRegex = '/^2016-11-26/'; 
$this->db->{$collection}->count(['date_authenticated' => array('$regex'=>new MongoRegex($startsWithRegex))]);
```

However I recommend you reading [Find objects between two dates MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb) as you can perform better queries if you handle dates properly.

Comment: Useful answer can I use this `$startsWithRegex = '/^'.$tdate.'/';` ?

Comment: Yes this should be possible