# mogodb RegEx returns all records when one letter in pattern

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have a collection (table in RDBMS) in mongodb that contains names of mail receivers.

A Name may contain normal english characters or Japanese characters or combination of both.

I am using `RegExp` to find names which match with pattern I am passing, below is code

```
db.user_logs.find({ "recipientName": new RegExp(".*漢字*", "i") })
```

This returns all records which contains **"漢字"** at any position within name

but when i use

`db.user_logs.find({ "recipientName": new RegExp(".*漢*", "i") })`

it returns all records whether it contains **"漢"** or not.

my requirement is i need only those records in which **"漢"** exists at any position

same is happening for english characters.

Comment: I think you might reach a wider audience here if you show failing test cases using english characters if you believe that to be the case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like

Comment: In case of querying MongoDB your regular expressions are identical to `/漢/` and `/.*/` correspondingly. Use [RegExp debugger](https://www.regex101.com/) to see how your regular expressions are actually work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check that certain sequence of character<sup>1</sup> appear in the name, the regex can be as simple as:

```
db.user_logs.find({ "recipientName": new RegExp("漢字", "i") })
db.user_logs.find({ "recipientName": new RegExp("漢", "i" })
```

<sup><sup>1</sup> If the string contains meta-characters (characters with special meaning in regex), you need to escape them.</sup>

The `i` flag is redundant for Chinese and Japanese characters, but I leave it there in case you need to use Latin search string.

There is also the option of using literal regex if the regex is fixed:

```
db.user_logs.find({ "recipientName": /漢字/ })
db.user_logs.find({ "recipientName": /漢/ })
```

`i` flag removed here, since you don't need it.

Comment: This is correct.. but I am using doctrine with symfony can u suggest solution how to write using doctrine. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799938/mongodbdoctrine-how-to-use-find-with-pattern-matching

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I think you should change the last * to a +

```
*
```

Means 0 or more matches, so it's optional.

```
db.user_logs.find({ "recipientName": new RegExp(".*漢.*", "i") })
           or
db.user_logs.find({ "recipientName": new RegExp(".*漢+", "i") })
```

Comment: The OR part is simply redundant.