# MongoDB+Doctrine How to use find with pattern matching

Tags: regex, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

I am using Mongo DB with doctrine. I want to do pattern matching like below

```
db.user_logs.find({ "recipientName": /user1/i })
```

without using `MongoRegex` class

```
$qb->field('recipientEmail')->equals(new \MongoRegex('/.*'.$textToSearch.'.*/i'));
```

purpose is to reach solution without creating class (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best way, but it works:

```
$qb->where("function(){ var patt = /".$textToSearch."/i; return patt.test(this.recipientEmail);}");
```