# Text Search with Mongodb and PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

Is it possible to query mongodb by matching the keywords or a date range in the record?

For example if I have a collection with fields such as "Title", "Author" and "Date". I have this record with Title as "hello world", author as "john billy", date as "2014/05/12".

Is it possible to return this record by entering either "world" or "billy" or a date range (2014/01/12 to 2014/06/12)

How should I write my query to get the record I want?

Thanks in advance!

below is my code for date period: $from_Id is the

```
        $rangeQuery = array('timestamp' => array( '$gte' => $from_Id, '$lte' => $to_Id ));

        $cursor = $collection->find($rangeQuery);
```

Comment: Below link may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like

Comment: Thank you! It works just fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use `$lt`/`$lte` (correspond to < / <=) and `$gt`/`$gte` (correspond to > / >=) operators to set a date range in your query. Just look for the mongodb documentation :

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/

Here is an example from the php doc (http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php) :

```
<?php

$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->selectDB('test');
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'phpmanual');

// search for documents where 5 < x < 20
$rangeQuery = array('x' => array( '$gt' => 5, '$lt' => 20 ));

$cursor = $collection->find($rangeQuery);
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
    var_dump($doc);
}

?>
```

The link given by @SaTya will help you to make a search with keywords.

Comment: Thank you, but I retrieved zero record using this query. Is it because it does not work with date? maybe only work with number?

Comment: It depends on how your dates are stored in your database. If you have timestamps you can use the same query as in the example :
`$rangeQuery = array('date' => array('$gt' => 1422745200, '$lt' => 1423004400));`
But if you store a string like this one : "2015-02-02" i think that the best way is to convert it into timestamp first and make the query after.