# Stop mongodb from ignoring special characters?

Tags: mongodb

```
Model.find({ $text : {$search: "#text"} })
```

returns everything that includes "text", not only those documents with "#text". I've tried putting an \ before the #, to no avail. How do I stop mongodb from ignoring my special characters? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to query mongodb with "like"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)

Comment: `$text` is a full text search. It does not work for exact sub-string matches, it searches word forms and phrases, just like a search engine. Use are regex for exact matches.

Comment: If I search for "xtext" then the document with "text" doesn't show up, why is it different for "#text"?

Comment: Because, as I said, `$text` is a *full text search*. It breaks up a string into words and stores those words (and *word forms*, so that `'text'` and `'texts'` are the same thing) in an index. You can then search through that index. `'text'` and `'xtext'` are end up as separate words. `'#text'` on the other hand will be broken up as `'text'`, because a full text index ignores symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomalak's description of how text indexing works is correct, but you can actually use a text index for an [exact phrase match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#search-for-a-phrase) on a phrase with a special character:

```
> db.test.drop()
> db.test.insert({ "_id" : 0, "t" : "hey look at all this #text" })
> db.test.insert({ "_id" : 1, "t" : "text is the best" })
> db.test.ensureIndex({ "t" : "text" })

> db.test.count({ "$text" : { "$search" : "text" } })
2
> db.test.count({ "$text" : { "$search" : "#text" } })
2

> db.test.find({ "$text" : { "$search" : "\"#text\"" } })
{ "_id" : 0, "t" : "hey look at all this #text" }
```

Exact phrase matches are indicated by surrounding the phrase in double quotes, which need to be escaped in the shell like `"\"#text\""`.

Text indexes are larger than normal indexes, but if you are doing a lot of case-insensitive exact phrase matches then they can be a better option than a standard index because they will perform better. For example, on a field `t` with an index `{ "t" : 1 }`, an exact match regex

```
> db.test.find({ "t" : /#text/ })
```

performs a full index scan. The analogous (but not equivalent) text query

```
> db.test.find({ "$text" : { "$search" : "\"#text\"" } })
```

will use the text index to locate documents containing the term `"text"`, then scan all those documents to see if they contain the full phrase `"#text`".

Be careful because text indexes aren't case sensitive. Continuing the example above:

```
> db.test.insert({ "_id" : 2, "t" : "Never seen so much #TEXT" })

> db.test.find({ "t" : /#text/ })
{ "_id" : 0, "t" : "hey look at all this #text" }

> db.test.find({ "$text" : { "$search" : "\"#text\"" } })
{ "_id" : 0, "t" : "hey look at all this #text" }
{ "_id" : 2, "t" : "Never seen so much #TEXT" }
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't think that `$text` could be used that way. Good to know.

Comment: If there a way to do multiple search phrases? Searching for 'text othertext' would return documents that contain either text OR othertext, is this possible with exact search phrases?