# Full Text Search in MongoDB not yielding the expected result for "@@@"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So I have a document in a collection with on of the fields having a value "@@@"
I indexed the collection and tried running the query:

`db.getCollection('TestCollection').find({$text:{$search:"\"@@@\""}})`

But it didn't show the result

How can I work around this?

Sample Document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b90dc6d3de8562a6ef7c409"),
"field" : "value",
"field2" : "@@@"
}
```

Comment: Post an example of the document in question.

Comment: You might want to check out this including the comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380179/stop-mongodb-from-ignoring-special-characters

Comment: What is your goal in searching for `@@@`? Is that a placeholder for something?

Answer (score 2):

Text search is designed to index strings based on [language heuristics](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/). Text indexing involves two general steps: [tokenizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Tokenization) (converting a string into individual *terms* of interest) followed by [stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) (converting each term into a root form for indexing based on language-specific rules).

During the tokenizing step certain characters (for example, punctuation symbols such as `@`) are classified as word separators (aka *delimiters*) rather than text input and used to separate the original string into terms. Language-specific [stop words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) (common words such as "the", "is", or "on" in English) are also excluded from a text index.

Since your search phrase of `@@@` consists entirely of delimiters, there is no corresponding entry in the text index.

If you want to match generic string patterns, you should use [regular expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) rather than text search. For example: `db.getCollection('TestCollection').find({field2:/@@@/})`. However, please note the caveats on [index usage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use) for regular expressions.

Comment: @PrateekNarendra I'd suggest posting a new question with details on the actual outcome you are trying to achieve (rather than this text search approach which won't work if you want to match `@@@`). It would be helpful to include your specific version of MongoDB server and more context on the use case (such as additional sample documents and an explanation of the importance of  `@@@`). Regular expressions definitely have usage caveats and there are likely more efficient ways to model your data to support your search use case.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has to many curly braces, remove them:

```
db.getCollection('so2').find({$text:{$search:"\"@@@\""}})
```

If you run it, Mongo tells you you're missing a text index. Add it like this:

```
db.so2.createIndex( { field2: "text" } )
```

The value you're using is pretty small. Try using longer values.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. While I agree there is an unnecessary set of curly braces in his $search, the issue is with the special characters that are not returned as a result. Mongo probably isn't going to tell him he's missing a text index, as he stated he already created one. I assume you were missing the index during your testing. The length of the query doesn't matter.

Comment: @Clouren I have created a text index on all fields in the collection