# Checking if a field contains a string (with punctuation)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

As per this post [Checking if a field contains a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610131/checking-if-a-field-contains-a-string) and the reply from okoboko.

I have created an index on one of my fields within my collection. If I use something like:

```py
db.users.find( { $text: { $search: "son" } } )
```

The query is fast and it's great however I want to query my index using punctuation (since my text field contains urls). If I wanted to retrieve all documents that are related to stackoverflow, I have tried to use:

```py
for page in myCollection.find( { "$text": { "$search": "\"stackoverflow\.com\"" } } ):
    print (page['_id'])
```

But this does not work. What is the fastest way of searching a collection for fields which contain a string with punctuation?

I do not get an error but my code gets stuck and does not return anything, as I explore Task Manager I can see python is eating up my memory and MongoDB server is working hard too.

When I use this bit of code, the return is super fast but I want to include `.com` too.

```py
for page in myCollection.find( { "$text": { "$search": "\".stackoverflow\"" } } ):
    print (page['_id'])
```

When I use this bit of code, I get a return but its about the same return time as using `$regex`:

```py
for page in ScrapedPagesCollection.find( { "$text": { "$search": "\"stackoverflow.com\"" } } ):
    print (page['_id'])
```

Comment: This thread sort of answer my question but I can't get it right. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380179/stop-mongodb-from-ignoring-special-characters

Comment: Please can you add in the error you are getting.

Comment: I've added some more information.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import pymongo

db = pymongo.MongoClient()['mydatabase']
db.mycollection.insert_one( { 'site': 'https://www.stackoverflow.com' } )
db.mycollection.create_index([('site', pymongo.TEXT)])

print(list(db.mycollection.find( { '$text': { '$search': 'stackoverflow.com' } } )))
```

gives:

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('5e3584b1534c1043defcd5bb'), 'site': 'https://www.stackoverflow.com'}]
```

Comment: Maybe there's an issue with me using the `_id` as the `url`