# How can I do a $regex call with SharpRepository?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, sharp-repository

We are using [SharpRepository](https://github.com/SharpRepository/SharpRepository). How can we do a [LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like) call or use [regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what LINQ statements the MongoDb LINQ driver can handle, but I would start by trying something like

```
repo.Find(x => x.Name.Contains("jeff"));
```