# Mongodb regext with c# driver

Tags: c#, regex, mongodb

I have this query running natively ok, but throws an exception when running in .net

```
FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filter = "{'$and':[ {'A':{$ne:'1'}},{'B': {$regex:/.*Ios.*/i}}]}";
collection.Find(filter);
```

via .net I get the exception: `JSON reader expected a string but found '/.*Ios.*/i'.`

I believe it is because the regex value is not wrapped with quotes.

Whats the deal here?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like) might help you

Comment: Don't expect either part of the query to be any fast. `$ne` is slow, and non-rooted regexs are slower. As to the question, .net requires you to explicitly create a `BsonRegularExpression`.

Comment: @yogesh - the problem is with the c# driver, what you have offered is not, thanks.

Comment: @mnemosyn  please explain. this is the only way I see to do string,cintains, thanks