# How I query array type via Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a document with property is an array like:

```
{
  name: ['Clark', 'Memphe', 'Alberto', 'Traicl']
}
```

I want query with keyword = 'cl' and I purpose the return will be

```
['Clark', 'Traicl']
```

How I can query with this conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
db.collection.find({"name": /.*cl.*/})
```

Comment: Tks bro. Im not sure it is too simple. I think the query need some operations like "$or" and "$like". Tkz u again!

Comment: You could refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like

Comment: This would be case sensitive. An `i` after the regex should make this case insensitive

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can take is to use the aggregation framework. The aggregation pipeline would have the initial step **[`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** that filters the documents with the name array that matches the regex pattern. Further down the pipeline you would need an **[`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator which essentially turns one document into many. Another **[`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline stage would be necessary to filter those deconstructed array documents and then a final **[`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** step to aggregate the matched documents through the **[`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** accumulator operator. So the following pipeline operation:

```
var re = new RegExp(/.*cl.*/i)
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": { "name":  re }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$name"
    },
    {
        "$match": { "name": re }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "name": {
                "$push": "$name"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

will give the result:

```
{ "_id" : null, "name" : [ "Clark", "Traicl" ] }
```