# query mongodb with "like" on number of fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to query MongoDB on the number of the fields: name, phone, email.
And the query should support `"like"` syntax: `'%s%'`
What is the better way to perform it:

1. Query on number of fields with $or
2. Create array field with values of the above fields and multikey index on this field

An example collection contains the following documents

```
{
    name: "Evgeny3345",
    phone: "4678946",
    email: "trial@stack.com"
},
{
    name: "bug",
    phone: "84567521",
    email: "bug@stack.com"
},
{
    name: "bug2",
    phone: "84567521",
    email: "deny@stack.com"
 }
```

When I find all documents with name or phone or email containing `"eny"`, this should return documents 1 and 3.

Comment: Do you have some example data to clarify your question with, together with the expected output of the required query?

Comment: added example data and expected result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query mongodb with "like"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)

Comment: Its different because I'm asking what is the best way to query "like" on number of fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best create a **[`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)** object with the search pattern and use that with the $or expression that references all the three fields. Something like

```
var rgx = new RegExp('ny', 'i'),
    query = {
        "$or": [
            { "name": rgx },
            { "phone": rgx },
            { "email": rgx }
        ]
    };
db.collection.find(query)
```

**Sample output:**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("562cf265d3ea50dcd6085c52"),
    "name" : "Evgeny3345",
    "phone" : "4678946",
    "email" : "trial@stack.com"
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("562cf265d3ea50dcd6085c54"),
    "name" : "bug2",
    "phone" : "84567521",
    "email" : "deny@stack.com"
}
```