# Rails active record where method error with passing two parameters With Mongo Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I am Writing a Query to get values from Database using Get Response.Everything is Okfrom the response side.But,I am struggling with the Query in the Model.

`@scroll = Scroll.where("name = %?%","#{params[:name]}")`

This Query has two arguments i Know.But this is Query Given in the 
url in Ruby on rails Docs.[Here:](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#Conditions)

I can retrieve the value by using the Query:

`@scroll = Scroll.where(name: params[:name])`

This above query works if the whole word Matches.I want it to accept a letter and find the word that contains the letter.
I am making a auto completion search box.so,i need a query Which Gives the rows which contain the letter inside the value of the column under name as user type.
I am Working with **MongoDB**

Posting FullTrace:

```
mongoid (5.0.1) lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:449:in `where'
(eval):2:in `where'
app/controllers/scrolls_controller.rb:4:in `index'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
/home/ashrith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/ashrith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/ashrith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: If this gives you error it may mean that someone changes the `where` method either on the model or on ActiveRecord class somewhere.

Comment: Can you search your code for `def where`?

Comment: Also, can you post a full backtrace?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I can search using `where`

Comment: your question title is "wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)", does it have anything to do with the problem?!

Comment: @MichalSzyndel: It has everything to do with the question because Mongoid's `where` only takes one argument. Of course, the Mongoid part was hidden in the stack trace and the MongoDB part was hidden in the middle of the question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I asked this question before the edit :/ Look at the answers which are completely not connected to mongo, clearly no one got what was asked.

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to accept a letter and find the word that contains the
>   letter.

This should work:

```
@scroll = Scroll.where("name LIKE ?","%#{params[:name]}%")
```

**Update:** 
I'm not familiar with mongodb myself, but perhaps something like this will work:

```
<your_table>.find({"name": /.*params[:name].*/})
```

For reference also see: 
[How to query MongoDB with "like"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like?rq=1)

Comment: Ahh! I missed he didn't write `LIKE` . :)

Comment: The OP is using Mongoid/MongoDB, not ActiveRecord/SQL, there is no LIKE in MongoDB nor is can you use SQL snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Mongoid and MongoDB so you can't use little SQL snippets (such as `'name = ?'`) with `where`. Mongoid's `where` only understands a single Hash, hence the complaint about the wrong number of arguments. Similarly, you can't use `%` and LIKE in the query because that's SQL and MongoDB doesn't understand SQL.

This works:

```
Scroll.where(name: params[:name])
```

because you're only passing `where` a single Hash argument. But this:

```
Scroll.where('name = ?', params[:name])
```

is trying to use SQL with MongoDB and that doesn't work.

If you want to do a pattern match with MongoDB then you can use a regex:

```
Scroll.where(:name => /#{Regexp.escape(params[:name])}/i)
```

Note that I'm using `Regexp.escape` to properly escape anything in `params[:name]` that is also regex syntax, I'm also doing a case-insensitive match.