# How to find the element based on its name in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I need to find the object whose name is `"abc"` from category collection in mongodb. Here is the my code

```
[{
    _id: 728e38e7,
    name: 'abc,def,ghi,klm,nmo',
    place: "mys"
},
{
    _id: 2788,
    name: 'djhd',
    place: "bang"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
var query = { name: new RegExp('^' + abc) };
collection.find(query).toArray(function(err, items))
```

Comment: Instead of using collection.find(query).toArray(function(err, items)).. Can we use findOne method??

Answer (score 0):

Using the mongo shell you can use find().

```
db.collection.find({"name" : /abc/}).
```

From this post : [How to query MongoDB with "like"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-do-i-query-mongodb-with-like)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the simplest method of using regex to find element based on name in mongodb :

```
db.collection.find({name:{$regex:"ABC",$options:"$i"}})
```

Here $i is used to make the search case insensitive.