# Sort documents based on first character in field value

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a set of data like this:

```
[{name: "ROBERT"}, {name: "PETER"}, {name: "ROBINSON"} , {name: "ABIGAIL"}]
```

I want to make a single mongodb query that can find:

1. Any data which name starts with letter "R" (regex: ^R)
2. Followed by any data which name contains letter "R" NOT AS THE FIRST CHARACTER, like: peteR, adleR, or caRl

so it produces:

```
[{name: "ROBERT"}, {name: "ROBINSON"}, {name: "PETER"}]
```

it basically just display any data that contains "R" character in it but I want to sort it so that data with "R" as the first character appears before the rest

So far I've come out with 2 separate query then followed by an operation to eliminate any duplicated results, then joined them. So is there any more efficient way to do this in mongo ?

Comment: Criteria (2) is unclear. It seems like you want the document where `name` contains `R`. If that is the case then [How do I query mongodb with “like”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-do-i-query-mongodb-with-like)

Comment: no, I just edited my question to give more clarity. I want to : display all the data where `name` contains `R` but I want to sort it so data with "R" as the first character appears before the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is add a [weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighting) to you documents and sort them accordingly.

First you need to select only those documents that [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) your criteria using regular expressions.

To do that, you need to [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) your documents and add the "weight" based on the value of the first character of your string using a logical [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)ition processing.

The condition here is [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) which add *weight* `1` to the document if the lowercase of the first character in the name is "r" or 0 if it's not.

Of course the [`$substr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) and the [`$toLower`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/)  string aggregation operators respectively return the the first character in lowercase.

Finally you [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort) your documents by weight in descending order.

```
db.coll.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": { "name": /R/i  } }, 
        { "$project": { 
            "_id": 0, 
            "name": 1, 
            "w": { 
                "$cond": [ 
                    { "$eq": [ 
                        { "$substr": [ { "$toLower": "$name" }, 0, 1 ] }, 
                        "r" 
                    ]}, 
                    1, 
                    0
                ]
            }
        }}, 
        { "$sort": { "w": -1 } } 
    ] 
)
```

which produces:

```
{ "name" : "ROBERT", "w" : 1 }
{ "name" : "ROBINSON", "w" : 1 }
{ "name" : "PETER", "w" : 0 }
```

Comment: it's unexpected. Thank you. On the side note though, what should I do if I want to replace my sorting basis from single character to regular expression ? My project demands document sorting based on the first "word/query" that user input

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
db.collectioname.find ("name":/R/)
```

Comment: what it is trying to accomplish ? yes sure it'll display all the data that contains "R" in it but i want to sort it so that "data with R as the first character appears before the data with R as the middle character"