# How to use "value%" with like keyword in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I can execute below query in MongoDB

MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id like "bc%;
```

MongoDB:

```
db.users.find( { user_id: /^bc/ } )
```

The above query is working. But below query is not working anyone please me give suggestion.

MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id like "%bc";
```

MongoDB:

```
db.users.find( { user_id: /bc^/ } );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Regex the `^` character labels the start of the subject. Putting it on the right hand side is therefore not meaningful.

Instead, the "end of the string" analogue to `^` is `$`:

```
db.users.find( { user_id: /bc$/ } );
```

This translates to: Find users where the last two characters of the `user_id` attribute are 'bc'.

Answer (score 1):

That would have to be:

```
db.users.find({"name": /.*m.*/})
```

or, similar,

```
db.users.find({"name": /m/})
```

You're looking for something that contains "m" somewhere (SQL's '%' operator is equivalent to regexp's '.*'), not something that has "m" anchored to the beginning of the string.

**Please check for more Info:** [How to query MongoDB with "like"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-do-i-query-mongodb-with-like)