# How to use the "OR" and "LIKE" statement in mongodb with cakephp3

Tags: mysql, mongodb, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using "hayko/mongodb" vendor.

One thing that I don't really get is how to perform a "LIKE" and "OR" statement in cakephp using MONGODB.

I tried this statement:

```
$this->find('all', array('conditions' => array('OR' => array(array('firstname like' => $name),array('lastname like' => $name)))));
```

but its not working since "LIKE" is an mysql function.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I query mongodb with "like"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-do-i-query-mongodb-with-like)

Comment: Thank you @BadHorsie. But it is not duplication. I am asking for cakephp + mongodb.