# how to check the second character match in mongoDB. in sql we are using like '_a%'. how to use in mongoDB?

Tags: regex, mongodb, search, field, using

how to check the second character match in mongoDB. in sql we are using  like '_a%'. how to use in mongoDB??

Comment: You accomplish this by using a regex as answered by others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-do-i-query-mongodb-with-like and

Answer (score 0):

you should use syntax like below:-

> db.users.find({"name": /.*a.*/})
>   or like >> db.users.find({"name": /a/})
>
> > if you want to search for character "a"