# How to do contain search in Nodejs And Mongodb

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

**NodeJS**

```
search_key = new RegExp('.*' + req.params.search_key + '.*', 'i');
Item.find({product_name:search_key}).exec(function (err, items) {
    console.log(items) );
});
```

Here I can search product name with the **search_key**. But my problem is, my product name is "`COMPLAN MILK BISCUITS 100GM`". If I search with "`BISCUITS COMPLAN`", its not finding that product. I need to find "`BISCUITS COMPLAN`" and "`COMPLAN BISCUITS`"  based on contain in search.

Comment: Not complitly sure of what you ask. You want "BISCUITS COMPLAN" to find all products who contain either BISCUITS or COMPLAN ? Or both without being specific order ?

Comment: Did you try a solution like: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-do-i-query-mongodb-with-like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-do-i-query-mongodb-with-like)

Comment: @SimonPA I have an item with product name complan milk biscuits 100gm.If I search with keyword Complan, Its getting that item. But if I search with Biscuits Complan, Its not finding that item. I need to find that Item If we search with keyword Biscuits Complan.

Comment: Since you explicitly search for your "search_key" **somewhere** (that is what you do when adding `.*` before and after forming your regexp), you will never be able to match "complan milk biscuits 100gm" with a search term that this string does not include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create text index to achieve your goal and then search from text indexed field. mongo shell command to create [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-text/#create-text-index) for `product_name` field

```
db.colectionName.createIndex( { product_name: "text" } );
```

then you can search using `$text` and  `$search` . [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/text/#match-any-of-the-search-terms)

```
db.collectionName.find({ $text: { $search: "BISCUITS COMPLAN" } });
```

no need to use `new RegExp(` just can use like:

```
Item.find({ $text: { $search: req.params.search_key } }).exec(function (err, items) {
    console.log(items) );
});;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`$text`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) operator for that.

So instead of:

```
Item.find({product_name: search_key})...
```

Something like:

```
Item.find({product_name: {$text: {$search: search_key}}})...
```

Note: You need to have a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) for that.