# How can I perform like query for big decimal number containing decimal part in it in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have perform like query in mongodb. I have following document in `employee collection` as:

```
{
   "_id" :1
   "name":"Abc",
   "salary": 56789.98456
 }
```

So far,I have performed `like query` to match the above employee document. I have tried following queries in mongo:

```
db.employee.find({"salary":/.*56789.98.*/}).pretty()
db.employee.find({"salary":/^56789.98/}).pretty()
db.employee.find({"salary":/56789.98/}).pretty()
```

But it doesn't work.
I also looked at:
[How to query MongoDB with "like"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)

How do I achieve this in mongo ?

Comment: what you want to accomplish ?

Comment: You need to store salary as double and also  then fetch it with the query

Comment: Salary is already stored as double in the above collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
db.employee.find({"$where":"/^56789.98.*/.test(this.salary)"})
```