# sluggish regular expression in mongo python

Tags: python, regex, mongodb

I have a query in mongo python which looks like:

```
collection.find({"name" : {$in : ["foo_foo", "bar_bar"]}})
```

And I'd like now to match names like "foo_bar", "foo_foe" etcetera. So I used a regular expresion:

```
collection.find({ $or : [{"name" : {"$regex" : "foo_.*" }}, 
   {"name" : {"$regex" : "bar_.*" }}] })
```

But when looking for lots of entries, the second query is thousands of times slower. I don't see how to improve this. Any hint would be much appreciated. What really surprises me is that matching a "foo_foo" string should be slower than matching a string "foo_.*".

Comment: [Have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like) There is a hint that you can imporve performance by using an index for a "starts with" search.

Comment: thanks Ingle but my collection does not have an index. Neither I can build one: I dont own the db. The query with full string is fast enought to be acceptable. But the regex is about 100 times slower.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this instead:

```
collection.find({ $or : [{"name" : {"$regex" : "^foo_" }}, 
   {"name" : {"$regex" : "^bar_" }}] })
```

or even

```
collection.find({"name" : {"$regex" : "^(foo|bar)_" }})
```

You should see a drastic improvement of the execution time. The reason being that your regular expression is effectively searching for "foo_" inside a string, not necessarily from the start of the string. So it would match "foo_" as well as "someotherfoo_" but in the latter case it would need to parse all the way to the end of the string.

Be sure you also read and understand that part of the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use):

> Additionally, while /^a/, /^a.*/, and /^a.*$/ match equivalent
>   strings, they have different performance characteristics. All of these
>   expressions use an index if an appropriate index exists; however,
>   /^a.*/, and /^a.*$/ are slower. /^a/ can stop scanning after matching
>   the prefix.

Beyond that there's not a lot you can do if you cannot add an index, I suppose.

Comment: I understand the docs. And I agree with adding ^. But for me matching /^a/ and /^a.*/ is exactly the same /^a/ will stop after matching. So it should do  /^a.*/ . Of course /^a.*$/ will be slower. But once again matching "foo_bar" should be slower than matching "foo_.*": we only have to compare the first four characters in the former case. In the first case we have to compare the 7 chars. The regex should be faster.

Comment: The `.` character can have different meanings depending on engine settings like multi line vs. single line which, I guess, is part of the reason why the engine does not just ignore .* at the end of a regex.

Comment: Yes perhaps /^a.*/ scans until end or new line. Being perl compatible dot . matches any char but the new line. OK fair enought. Still this does not explains why matching "foo_bar" is significantly faster than matching "^foo_"?

Comment: Is it still a lot faster? **With** the caret sign?

Comment: It could be that it's because of the `$or`... Let me see if I can combine the two regexs into one.

Comment: Yes it is faster. But the query with full text "foo_bar" executes in 0.5s. The query (It bring more elements of course) "^foo" takes about 3 minutes. "foo_.*" takes about 12 minutes

Comment: Try using .explain(): https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/

Comment: Sorry "^foo" takes 10s.