# Mongo Search query by word starting letters

Tags: mongodb

I am worked on my current project with MONGO, I need a query if i am search a letter need to search every word

ex: I have 3 topics named in my db as below

> **chemistry, chemical, organic chemistry**

i tried with query like below

```
db.topics.find({name: { '$regex': '^che', '$options': 'i' }}, {})
```

but i am getting results of **chemistry and chemical** only

but my requirement is if i search with **che** then that letter need to check firtst letters of every word and  results comes with chemistry, chemical and **organic chemistry** also (because in organic chemistry have word starts with **che**mistry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
db.topics.find({name: { '$regex': 'che', '$options': 'i' }}, {})
```

^ in regex means "start" `^che` are text with start with `che`

and if u want **che** was first in any word u must match **spaces**:

```
db.topics.find({name: { '$regex': '(\s+che|^che)', '$options': 'i' }}, {})
```

for better understand regex check this : [https://www.regextester.com/](http://regex.com)

Comment: It does not works or me "\s" is unrecognized can you please help me

Comment: what is your problem ? `\s` mean space. `\s+` mean one or many spaces

Answer (score 1):

To search letters throw every word, you need to do something like 
`db.topics.find({name: '/che/'})` 
 For more detailed answer, please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)