# Find a document by a partial String value inside an array element on MongoDB from Azure

Tags: mongodb, azure, nosql

I'm trying to find all `lists` which the `person` `number` has `'-'` or `'.'` inside of it. I already tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3305687/2387977), but it's not working for elements **inside** of the array.

But when I try to find by the entire String, without the `regex` notation, the document is found.

Per example:

```
db.getCollection('list').find({"persons.number": "123456789"}) //works!

db.getCollection('list').find({"persons.number": /3/}) //not work...
db.getCollection('list').find({"persons.number": /.*3.*/}) //not work
db.getCollection('list').find({"persons.number": /.*..*/}) //not work
db.getCollection('list').find({"persons.number": /.*[-\.]+.*/}) //not work
```

If I try to find the document by some attribute **outside** of the array (an attribute from the `list`, per example), the `/3/`, `/.*3.*/` and `/.*[-\.]+.*/` **works**.

Document format:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5af3037ee8006c4a04e84b2f"),
    "id" : 1,
    "persons" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "number" : "123.123.123-22"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "number" : "123.456.789-11"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, what are the options?

I'm using the MongoDB from Azure. Executing the `db.version()` on console returns `3.2.0`.

Comment: Hi Dherik - could I ask you to double-check your document format? Two reasons why: I've tried with a copy of your example document and the first regex /3/ is working for me; also, your example document doesn't have an _id field at all.

Comment: You're using Azure Cosmos DB? I tried with MongoDB v3.4.14, accessed through Robo 3T.

Comment: Yes, `Cosmos`, not `Cloud`... sorry. The returned version from console is `3.2.0`

Comment: Could you copy the JSON of an example document i.e. including the _id and everything exactly as it really is in the database?

Comment: @VinceBowdren, I update my question with the Json document copied from MongoDB.

Comment: Testing on MongoDB v3.4.14 (not Cosmo DB), with a copy of your example document, all the regexes work just fine e.g. `"persons.number" : /3/`  or `"persons.number" : /-/`  or `"persons.number" : /\./`.

Comment: PS I deleted my earlier comments, as they are obsolete after your clarifications.

Comment: This is probably a problem from Azure MongoDB (CosmosDB)... I already found some limitations (like lacks of `$text` support). Is there some other way to make this search?

Answer (score 0):

The regex `.*[-\.]+.*` should work,

Try this,

```
db.getCollection('list').find({"persons.number": /.*[-\.]+.*/})
```

Comment: Not works... If I try to find the document by some attribute outside of the array (an attribute from the list, per example), the /3/, /.*3.*/ and /.*[-\.]+.*/ works.

Comment: I'm using MongoDB from Azure.

Answer (score 0):

For searching multiple patterns , i.e an OR of patterns the regex format is little different.

```
(pattern1)|(pattern2)
```

Tried the below mongo query on my local running 3.4.6 , but it should work on 3.2.x as well

```
db.list.aggregate([{"$unwind":{"path":"$persons"}},{"$project":{"_id":1,"persons.number":1}},{"$match":{"persons.number":{"$regex":/.*(\.)|(\-).*/}}},{"$group":{_id:"$_id"}}])
```